# When is the new Improving Feedback for All Users message coming?

Tags: support, blog

In August, [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/) was made with an exciting update on a new *closed question* view for both the author and for public users.

I was wondering if there is any word on when this new view is coming?

Comment: The staff appeared to have been a bit busy lately...

Comment: That was published 7 weeks ago. So, it's still within the 6-8 weeks timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post notices were rolled out on SO today with 50% of users seeing them:

- [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

They mention this on the StackOverflow Blog in the [Iterating on Inclusion](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) post:

> Over the next few months, you’re going to see a lot more of this from us. As part of this next phase of work, we’re going to work to fix features that make people feel like they’ve been publicly shamed, and reduce some of the social friction that is built into our product. Soon, there will be no more big yellow boxes that say “these five people voted your question is bad,” because nobody likes that feeling! Instead, there will be clear guidance on how to improve questions when they need more information or better formatting.

So, they’re definitely still working on it. When we’ll actually see it, is unclear.

Comment: I remember Shog saying somewhere that something else will be looked at after when this thing here is finished but I don't remember where. It may mean it's close to finishing so that you can actually talk about what comes after.