# New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, post-notices, announcements

### New Post Notices [have been launched network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/51). Please post all new feedback, bugs and feature requests [to the new announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/51).

---

As has been [previously announced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/), we have been working for some time on a full refresh for post notices. I am happy to announce that all initial development work and testing has been completed, and that the new notices are now live on Stack Overflow.

During our initial launch period these will be shown to 50% of users (with the other 50% viewing notices as they have been with no change). After evaluating the impact of the notices during this period and making any warranted changes, our goal is to release these network-wide, and to completely remove the old notices from the system.

For our purposes, a 'post notice' includes any status banner shown on questions or answers: deleted, merged, migrated, closed, locked, protected, bountied, as well as any information notices that can be applied to posts by moderators.

The visual change in styling and position relative to content should immediately be obvious. The current notices use legacy styling and for the most part appear below the post (question or answer) content. The experience on mobile and desktop is different as the old layout is not flexible enough to be used on both. The new notices will all appear above post content, will feature a refreshed look and feel (using the [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) design framework), and will work identically on both desktop and mobile.

[image: A primarily opinion-based close message: "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question. Closed 13 days ago by Donna."]
<sub>A new post notice, being shown to users with the close/reopen privilege on a post closed as being opinion-based</sub>

Beyond the look and feel changes, we have also rewritten the language for all of the different messages, with the goal of making them more friendly and results-driven, and taking into account the changing ways in which the notices have been used over the years. New messages language has been guided by our [Content Style Guide](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles), which itself is based on user insights and best practices. We hope that the language refresh will make it clearer to users what each respective notice is for, and if appropriate, to provide clearer instructions as to what they can do in order to improve the content that was flagged.

As Meg [wrote in her blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/):

> For people who ask questions today, if your question is closed, feedback that is directed toward you privately is shared publicly with anyone who views your question. Plus, the names of people who voted to close the question are highlighted publicly, too, setting them up for attack when they’re just trying to curate content according to the system.
>
> Here’s what our holistic redesign of all post notices will prioritize:
>
> - Delivering improved, private feedback to post authors
> - Not putting users who curate content on the spot
> - Giving actionable, understandable information for the vast majority of public viewers

The change affects all post notices, including mod notices, post locks, migration notices, and every single type of close notice. Many of these feature different messages that will be shown to the post owner, users with close/reopen privilege, and everyone else, with each message designed to expose the information that will be most helpful to the viewer. Another goal is also to provide more instructions and options for post owners when it comes to taking steps to edit the content of closed questions in order to allow for them to be reopened.

[image: A duplicate close message: "Some community members have associated this post with similar questions. Closed 2 hours ago by Frederico klez Culloca, Community."]
<sub>A duplicate closed notice being shown to the post owner.</sub>

This is a far-reaching project and is also touching other related content like the [wording used in the close menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3csjy.png) giving [guidance on off-topic reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwwx3.png) and the [instructions being shown at the top of the review queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTi4P.png). Additionally, the notification language, user workflow, and options being provided to post owners on questions where there are active close as duplicate flags has been modified to give post owners more leeway in preemptively accepting or rejecting potential duplicate posts.

This new set of features and improvements is the first of a series of related projects aimed at improving the user experience on question close workflows and review queues for all users. Our goal is to better facilitate feedback and content curation for all people who code, whether they are new to programming and Stack Overflow, are seasoned moderators and technology experts, or fit anywhere in between.

[image: An old "On Hold" notice]
[image: A new "On Hold" notice]
<sub>Old and new "On Hold" notices</sub>

General feedback is welcome on this post, as are [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports. We promise to read everything, and will do our best to engage with the community to address concerns that are raised.

### FAQs

#### When will the changes roll out on SO?

The changes are live on SO right now

#### I still see the old notices and I would rather see the new ones

*OR*

#### I see the new notices and would rather keep the old notices

During our initial launch period the new post notices (and all related changes) are being shown to 50% of users. There is no easy way to switch between the group of users seeing old or new notices. If there are things about the new notices that you dislike, please let us know in a respectful and constructive way. We are happy to receive and take all feedback into consideration.

#### What are you looking for during the initial launch period?

The primary goal of the project is to improve the friendliness of the user experience when viewing post notices. This is a hard thing to measure. Some of the indicators that we will be using are the levels of engagement by users who see old vs new post notices and the rates of closed posts being reopened (specifically focusing on post edits and post reopen votes).

#### Can you please release a list of all the changes that were made to all notice language and functionality?

We are not going to do this right now:

- There are *sooo* many changes that were made, that any attempt to document all of these in a clear way will probably still end up being confusing (and it will be challenging to keep this up to date as changes are made during the initial launch period).
- We feel that in order to properly evaluate the changes to presentation, language and functionality, the changes need to be seen in the context of the site, by users who encounter them through normal site usage. Thus, we prefer to evaluate the success of changes by presenting them to users who will encounter and interact with them through organic site usage.

#### After Meg's blog post that first mentioned these changes, a [post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332499/51) was made that solicited feedback on the preview given in the blog post. Were there any changes to this project that were made based on this feedback?

We read all of the feedback and found much of it to be very useful. Some of it was incorporated into this set of changes, and we hope to incorporate much more of it in a future project that builds on this one to address the underlying mechanics of the close->reopen workflows. Thanks for all the suggestions, and special shout out and thanks to [Journeyman Geek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135565/journeyman-geek) for initiating and organizing the feedback post on MSE!

#### How long will the initial launch run for? When will this go live for everyone?

The initial launch is slated to tentatively run for 2-3 weeks. While we cannot commit to a final go-live date at this point, as there are many unknowns involved, we can say that we are interested in getting the final product out as soon as we can.

#### What is the average air speed of an unladen swallow?

What do you mean? An African or a European Swallow?

#### European, of course

Approximately 11 meters per second (40 km/h; [24](http://style.org/unladenswallow/) - [25](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+the+airspeed+velocity+of+an+unladen+swallow) miles per hour)

Comment: Ok folks. Considering this is a positive change and I think having the Q&A team comfortable with meta, I shalt be quite cross with the next person who removes the swallow joke.

Comment: **To close-voters:** While this is currently implemented on SO only, this question clearly states that it's the intent to have this network-wide: "After evaluating the impact of the notices during this period and making any warranted changes, **our goal is to release these network-wide**, and to completely remove the old notices from the system." Thus, this is not an issue which only affects one specific site, the close reason selected by four people. It's clear that this question solicits feedback on the feature being used on all sites, even though the current examples are SO focused.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1415/discussion-on-question-by-yaakov-ellis-new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflo). I've left a few essential comments in place for immediate reference

Comment: Just coming in to say "yay" the Monty Python joke remains :P

Comment: Should bugs and feature requests be raised as separate questions?

Comment: @mifreidgem yes, they should.

Comment: @YaakovEllis https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5288/759

Comment: I don't agree with hiding the names of moderators. The primary problem this site faces is over moderation. Seeing names brings accountability. Need an example? I'm the 4th most upvoted user for 2022 on [devops.se]. Sounds impressive? I have **ONLY** 226 rep this year. That site is effectively dead though out of beta. Why does it struggle so bad? Look at the questions they're closing which I self-answered https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16159/18965? Why? I'm trying to be productive and seed a community where none exists. The mods need more accountability, not less.

Answer (score 165):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The notice for the duplicate closure doesn't mention the option to edit the question; the only option it offers is to "ask a new one". Sometimes (maybe even most of the times, it's hard to give an estimate) this is a far better option than posting a new question. I'll reiterate what I said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332500/295232):

> My gut feeling says it will only lead to repeated questions, worded slightly different but not enough to make it clear. If authors decide to *edit* their question without much improvement, then at least the question stays closed and requires no further caretaking (except maybe from the Reopen Votes review queue). If they post a new one, that's more work for the community *and* the author is more likely to hit a question ban.

Comment: Was just writing an answer on this. Note the old message does have this option _"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."_

Comment: Thanks @Glorfinder. This is a good point.

Comment: At least I'm happy that you implemented my suggestion for the other closure types :)

Comment: @YaakovEllis To add on to Glorfindel's point, if a user is new, they don't have a whole lot of questions they can ask before downvoted questions start to keep them from asking more. If I, as a new user, waste two question spots on a duplicate, it's not going to turn out well for me.

Comment: Plus, the community really hates when a user asks a new question instead of editing the old one. If you're going to change the policy like this, you need to retrain everyone. Just hoping people will notice the change while reading a message not directly related to it won't do.

Comment: I think "edit" is not a good option on duplicates that are more then a few days old.  Maybe the people who voted to close should be informed and able to withdraw their votes when a edit is done.

Comment: @IanRingrose you mean more specifically than just putting those questions in the reopen queue? I flag a lot of dupes in the R tag that then get completely trivial edits just to add something like "Totally not a dupe, that post makes blue dots and I want red ones." I'd be annoyed if I got notified each time that happens; much rather just handle them in the reopen review.

Comment: @camille, yes but it could be implemented as a custom reopen queue that only contains what I voted to close, with being notified when not empted.  Even better if in that case a 2nd down vote was allowed:=)

Comment: Worth noting here that editing has a *terrible* success rate for duplicates. There's already edit guidance - the asker is asked to edit the question after the first vote or flag arrives, and this does a lot of good... But *after* the question is closed, edits rarely do anything beyond clogging the reopen queue. Part of the problem here is that we don't give a lot of guidance specific to this situation to askers *when they're editing* - but we **do** provide this when they're asking! We'll review the data on this after its been live for a while & watch for unintended consequences.

Comment: Declned: Please see Shog's comment.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Shog's comment doesn't say it's not useful, just that the problem is elsewhere: in the guidance for people which questions are already closed. Once that is fixed, the desired effect would be achieved.

Comment: @Shog9 With only 3 votes necessary to reopen, the success rate should hopefully climb. And there is no edit guidance on dupe-hammered questions which get closed immediately.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Could you at least reword it to "*Ask a **different** question*", please? People simply re-posting the same question already happens. See also [more arguments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339734/183280).

Comment: There are a couple related posts that I’m linking here to find them more easily:
[“You can edit the question or post a new one”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/4642212),
[Add a statement about re-opening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339731/289905),
[Why doesn’t the system prevent repeating the _exact_ same question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/4642212).

Comment: @YaakovEllis Could this [status-declined] be reconsidered? Apparently [this confuses new users a lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/4284627).

Comment: Could you please raise this as a new feature request, now that the original reason for declining this is outdated? (Edits don’t clog the reopen vote queue anymore)

Answer (score 102):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I noticed that an automatic comment is added when I close as duplicate (a single close vote with my gold badge)

> Does this answer your question? [How to create an irregular square shape in css?](http://#) – Temani Afif 6 mins ago

Why is that? Shouldn't the OP edit their question to clarify if the duplicate is not suitable?

This comment will probably make us having a discussion about why it's not a duplicate instead of editing the post.

I close many questions each day, I may easily end with a lot a message about all the questions I closed and I won't be able to answer all of them.

Comment: I also don't like the wording in that comment. The old one wasn't _great_ but I don;t think this is an improvement.

Comment: If you now close a question as Dupe, you also post an auto comment. But perhaps this could be phrased so that it isn't a question.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder the old one disappear but the new one is added when the question is closed (I have a gold badge by the way)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh it's added _after_. I don't like that at all in that case. Users can ping close voters, even if it doesn't autocomplete the name. It would be better to make the autocomplete work than post a comment.

Comment: Absolutely. When I VTC a question, I *almost never* want to enter into a conversation with the OP about whether their question is a duplicate. Especially in the vast majority of cases, which are unsalvageable zero effort debug-me questions.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337031/51. We changed the auto-comment language, but bug in the auto-delete when closed

Comment: I see no value in this change at all other than to make it look less like an automated message and more like I'd actually written it (which I didn't). Please can we stop coddling people at the expense of actual communication :(

Comment: @YaakovEllis it seems to be fixed on my side

Comment: You also get the "Does this answer your question?" when you try to close a question that the same user has posted twice - it doesn't make sense here because I'm not trying to point them to a helpful answer - I'm trying to stop them spamming the same question

Comment: Update: the auto-delete logic is fixed for this, so the comment will be deleted when the post is closed. I am not marking this fixed yet, as I need to go back and clean up the comments that should have been deleted but were not while this bug was live over a few days.

Comment: @DavidW Yep exactly ... was laughing out loud when I first read that "Does this answer your question?" nonsense linking to duplicate of the same user without any answer and sure to be closed soon due to poor quality and total absence of relevant specifics (as it is usual for such cases)

Comment: I just noticed this starting to happen (maybe I haven't flagged as dupe in a bit?) and I absolutely hate it.  This wording is too passive.  I'm not _asking_ the OP if their question is a duplicate, I'm _telling them_ that it is.

Comment: The logic for this bug was fixed within a day of when it was reported. Marking it as completed now since I finally got around to fixing up the data, and deleting those comments that should have been auto-deleted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/confusing-comment-does-this-answer-your-question

Comment: No comment, not even the most harmless one, should ever be attributed to someone who didn't write it. What if the wording of the target question is very similar to the one being marked? That comment would look like sarcasm. But that's beside the point. Never, ever make something look like I said it.

Answer (score 94):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

> Rationale for status:
>
> One thing that needs to be called out here: there are now *three different descriptions* for each close reason.
>
> 1. The general public gets a very "firm" reason: "this question is opinion based".
> 2. The close voter gets a very nuanced description *when voting*: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."
> 3. And finally, authors / editors / reopen voters get specific instructions on what needs to be fixed: "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question."
>
> Before, we had only one bit of text that had to fulfill each of these purposes - and generally, none of them were optimal for any one purpose. They were less nuanced than they should've been as guidance for voters, less firm than they should've been as a statement of fact for readers, and... Well, guidance for editors was almost an after-thought.
>
> We don't *have* to compromise now, so... We're not.
>
> -- Shog9
>
> ---

In the two examples of close banners here, I notice that the wording has become more definitive:

> This question is opinion-based

> This question is off topic.

Previously these messages said:

> Closed as primarily opinion-based

> Closed as off topic

Additionally, the old off topic message had a subtext that said that the question *appears* to be off topic.

This change seems counterintuitive. Wouldn’t it be *more* jarring to new users to see a definitive statement that their question is objectively “bad” than to see a statement that only says that the subjective opinion of the following five users is that their question is “bad”?

Comment: This is especially important because *on many network sites (if maybe not SO)*, **some degree of "opinion-based" is the norm**. Each site needs to draw a line for what's *too*/primarily opinion-based, but closing a question just for being partially opinion-based wouldn't make sense on [philosophy.se] or [literature.se] or [interpersonal.se].

Comment: _Declined_: Being more definitive is a deliberate decision here. We want the post author to have clear direction, and for close voters to offer clear and decisive direction.

Comment: @YaakovEllis With the close reason even on SO being *primarily opinion-based*, wouldn't it at least make sense to have it say *This question is primarily opinion-based*? See Rand al'Thor's comment for an explanation.

Comment: @YaakovEllis "You suck. Sit down and shut up." is definitive and gives the person hearing it clear and decisive directions. That doesn't make it a good phrasing. -- There's probably a way to phrase things such that users get a clear directions on how to improve things, while not implying that they're necessarily objectively wrong if they disagree with the close reason.

Comment: @Randal'Thor On the sites you've mentioned, is the opinion-based close reason even relevant? Perhaps that close reason shouldn't be offered at all. If true, then there's nothing wrong with the close reason being definitive where it does apply.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Yes, it is. Well, I don't know anything about the Philosophy site, but I've [written](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/844/17) extensively [about](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/17) this issue on Literature meta. (I even mentioned as an important point that *the close reason doesn't say "opinion-based": it says "primarily opinion-based"*! Hence my comment above.)

Comment: @YaakovEllis We know it's a deliberate decision, no one is saying otherwise. What we are trying to say is that the change doesn't reflect how other SX sites work, which allow different degrees of subjectivity. If you are going for "being more definitive", you might want to remove that close option all together from those sites, or give an adequate reason that is compatible with each site's dynamic.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Alternative: each site may set an opinion-based close text, possibly from a set of pre-approved options. Just a few choices would really cover the gamut from the generic "this is a little too opinion-y" to the Law.SE "this is opinion based".

Comment: @YaakovEllis, The question can not be opinion-based. “Opinion-based” can be answers to the question. The short phrase doesn’t make sense  without clarification “answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions”. The public message should consider novices, who do not know SO jargon.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, how can I vote on original answer after Shog9 hijack it? Now when I upvote the answer, it looks like that I upvote decline of it.

Answer (score 94):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Hide this blurb and only show it on hover over the stricken-through eye icon:

> Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege.

[image]

This is meta information that does not need to be present and read every time someone looks at a close banner, but it should be available *if they want to read it*. I think putting it in a tooltip shown on hover of the "conditionally visible" icon is a good solution for that.

Comment: Yeah, as it is now I actually read that notice and assumed it meant the *post* was hidden.. It's just referring to the section of text though, right?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think so, yes. That's a good point; I hadn't considered it could be confused to mean the *entire question* might be hidden to others.

Comment: *`status-declined`*: This text will be removed as part of the upcoming project focusing on the Close Ux. We are going to keep it in place until then in order to ensure clarity for this section of the notice (not every user will know to mouse-over the icon).

Comment: @YaakovEllis Wouldn't that be "status-deferred"?

Comment: @TylerH this actual request is declined, because we are probably not going to implement it as requested (mouse-over on the icon). However, the spirit of the request is deferred until the next project.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Ah, I guess it's a miscommunication then; the *request* was to remove the text; the idea to show it on tooltip was simply a suggestion re: the request implementation details.

Comment: @TylerH in that case, the request is still declined. The text is going to stay for the time being. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: The worst thing about the blurb is not that it's shown to users who should already have learned about this and don't need it repeated every time, but that it is a **large and bold text in the middle of the box**. It's visually attracting my attention to the most irrelevant content inside that box.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Except that [it fails to ensure clarity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337020/183280) as well

Comment: This would be made more clear if that period was at least changed to a colon: "Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege: some community members...". Similarly with "Private feedback for you:". Right now it's "Sentence fragment. Sentence that may or may not be related to fragment.".

Comment: On MSO, @Cerbrus [has made some nice suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390990/1048572) of how this could be improved, with visual examples

Comment: @Bergi provided us (from Cerbrus) with exactly the examples we've been needing to further this discussion. I think there's a compelling case that the UX aspect of the new text is...subpar.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: Knowing who can see what is very useful.  I lost this ability when I became a mod (I see everything), and since then I've never been entirely sure what people see and do not see.  I agree with tylerh: keep the text as a tooltip under the eye.

Answer (score 86):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have a small suggestion:

**Show the exact reputation requirement on protected questions**, even if one has enough reputation.

[image: pic]

I, for one, still can't remember how much reputation is required. I think it'd be more informative to show the requirement in the notice:

> ... Since you have <s>X reputation</s> **more than Y reputation**, you can answer the question. ...

Comment: Agreed; I also requested this (along with many other things related to the banner) in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337053/253521)

Comment: Agreed. People don't need to be reminded how much reputation they have. That's shown in the topbar on every page (assuming they're using a wide enough screen). When changing this text to "more than Y reputation" it should either be customized for each user, or just be explicit that the requirement is >=10 reputation on the current site, exclusive of the association bonus. Previously, this notice didn't require any data about the user. Now, it requires knowing the user's reputation, which adds additional processing on every affected page, which could be eliminated with different wording.

Comment: The problem is that the reputation requirement is variable.  A user with 10 reputation probably can answer the question, while a user with 101 reputation probably can't -- it needs to be reputation earned on the site, not reputation from the association bonus.

Comment: IMHO this message is pointless... if I have enough reputation to answer, nothing has changed, so why tell me about it? I saw it earlier today and was like, "So what?" (I mean, if I didn't have enough to answer it, then sure that gives me some useful info)

Comment: As it is now, gives you only a little useful information. It says that you can, or can't, answer, which is good to know. People care about that. But, anyone looking at it doesn't care what their reputation is, or has other sources to know their reputation. If they can answer, then they almost never care about their reputation or the threshold (maybe they would care if they are within a downvote or two of loosing the privilege). If they can't answer, then what they care about is how much more reputation they need in order to answer, which this doesn't currently tell them.

Comment: We decided not to show how much is needed because the amount needed is for rep earned on the site, and does not include the association bonus. This distinction can be a complicated one to convey, and just listing the requirement can end up leading to more confusion. We will consider changing the language to be more rep-agnostic, something like "...because you have earned enough rep on this site..." or something like that.

Comment: @YaakovEllis You're already getting the user's reputation and determining if they are able to post an answer. That means you must also know if they have the association bonus. While, yes, it would be nice to explain what is generally necessary, all you really need to do is tell the user if they can post an answer and/or the amount of rep *they* need on the site in order to post an answer. It's certainly possible to give a very straight-forward statement to the user as to if *they* can answer and/or what rep *they* need to be able to answer. The full nuances wrt. everyone can be in a link.

Comment: @makyen yes, I understand. As I said, you make good points and we will consider changing the language of this notice.

Comment: We have changed the language to no longer list the current user's exact rep. It how says "You have enough reputation to answer this question..."

Comment: @YaakovEllis now it's not clear for users with the association bonus who didn't earn rep on the site itself. They have 101 reputation but see "Earn 10 reputation"  - it's confusing and several years ago [was changed to something more clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati). Can the message be clear again, e.g. add in brackets "Association bonus does not count"?

Answer (score 64):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems that the close vote reasons have been rewritten from scratch, which is only mentioned as an aside on this post.

Here's what "typo/no repro" is now:

> "It's caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

This no longer covers typos. We *don't* want to leave typos open, because they do *not* help future readers. I'm a bit worried that other subtleties have been missed while rewriting the close reasons. Is there a feedback post where we can suggest alternatives that *don't change how moderation has worked for years*? I tried finding one but couldn't.

Comment: I'd assume typos still fall under this umbrella, but it would be helpful for that to be spelled out. e.g. "It's caused by a typo or other problem that can no longer be reproduced."

Comment: @camille i.e. what it said originally? I agree ;)

Comment: haha I suppose so. I like it being a little more broad, since I often vote to close as typo for things that aren't *exactly* typos, like not adding a legend and then asking where the legend is, or incorrect syntax, and then I have to explain that it's basically the same as a typo

Comment: "Typos and syntax problems" seem different enough from "unreproducible problem" that you should consider putting them in different categories altogether.

Comment: @camille a typo *can* be reproduced. Enter the same wrong code, get the same error. But the point is these are too minor of a thing to help out future people, as the errors are too localised - e.g. somebody wrote "usre" instead of "user". It's unlikely that a future visitor will have the *exact* same misspelling in *exactly* the same circumstance. Even if they do, it's not even likely they'll find exactly this post.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica they are indeed different, but they should be closed for the same reason. We emphasized the "on topic but not helpful for future readers" part of the close reason. We already have a bit too many close choices, I'd rather we didn't proliferate them needlessly.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica Syntax wasn't really the right word I suppose. In the R tag, we have tons of questions where someone's making a chart with something that can have both a fill and a color, tells it color = blah, then posts a question asking why the fill didn't change. Well, you didn't tell it to. That isn't a typo exactly, but it falls into the category of you didn't actually write what you meant to write

Comment: As for syntax issues, if a function takes arguments x, y, z and you give it arguments x, z, y, it might not be a typo exactly, but it's definitely not that useful. But there isn't a RTFM close reason

Comment: Close reason has been changed to: **It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced.** While similar questions may be [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Comment: @YaakovEllis thank you very much for the quick fix!

Comment: @camille It sounds like the general category would be something to the effect of "A problem unlikely to be experienced by other readers", with typos and unreproducible problems as examples.

Comment: FYI "typo" is an informal shortened version of typographical error.

Comment: That gets us back into "Too Localized" territory, which... we were trying to get out of when this reason was originally added, @rockwalrus. There's a danger in making these reasons... *Too broad*...

Comment: @Shog9: I literally LOLed.

Answer (score 56):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Stating the closure date as "months passed since closure" doesn't seem particularly practical.

> [image]

For questions closed many years ago, we'd end up saying things like:

> Closed 92 months ago by Foobar.

If we are not showing the date as we do now:

> Closed as not constructive by Foobar Feb 29 '12 at 17:52

We should at least resolve the duration as years + months:

> Closed as not constructive by Foobar 7 years, 8 months ago

Comment: This is the same as: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337025/361484

Comment: Between the answer's formatting and it dealing with more than one issue on the same post, I had missed that. I'll leave this one up because of those reasons.

Comment: @yivi thanks, I'll look into this

Comment: Awesome @Yaakov. That's what I would expect. But I've seen users mentioning values of greater than 12 months in some other answers.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well, need to look into why (it is _supposed_ to be showing the highest unit that it can)

Comment: Relative post close times are now being shown accurately

Answer (score 52):

As [Journeyman Geek](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/#comment-294413) said, "put on hold" is way better than "closed" because if a question is on hold there is a opportunity to make it better while closed discloses the feeling that the question is closed for good and that takes away the goal of improving a question and just making a new one.

With that said, overall, the design of it and hiding the people who vote-closed it is a great feature. I would like to see a custom message from the people who closed it so the "private feedback" is not some canonical message that everyone is used too on the old version.

---

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303932/undefined-variable-with-class):

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) My question was closed on August 1st 2019 so it was closed approximately 2.9 months ago (instead of 29 months). While 2.9 is correct I would prefer a y:m:d format or the exact date. ([thanks @Luuklag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337025?noredirect=1#comment1118782_337025));
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag has an underline on it (for gold badge holders single-close). ([thanks @JL2210](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337025?noredirect=1#comment1119068_337025))

[image]

---

### Update

Now it's 0 months!

[image]

Comment: We went through changing the word from close years ago. As in computing close means lose the current state with no way of getting it back whilst we want the user to come back and edit. See many MSE and I like this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222677/136010

Comment: This is definetly a bug, as the question was closed august 1st this year, so 2.9 months ago approximately. I believe a decimal separator is lost along the way. @YaakovEllis

Comment: Another issue would be the underlining of the tag name.

Comment: @JL2210 I for one think that would be a good thing. It is a hyperlink after all, so better style it as one.

Comment: The space between the tag and the period, would be something to fix.

Comment: @Luuklag I didn't catch the space between the tag and the period. I must've assumed it was just a speck of dirt on my screen.

Comment: @Luklag Aren't all tags actually hyperlinks in virtually all places across the network, and without underlining? Why should this be any different?

Comment: I see a post closed 8 months ago and it says 23 months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613620/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-int-in-line-130-on-php

Comment: _"As in computing close means lose the current state with no way of getting it back"_ Does it? Close has prompted to save (and permitted re-opening) since like 1985....

Comment: Yep the closure time is quite wrong (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSlcp.png)

Comment: Closure times are now being shown accurately

Comment: The second issue reported here - underlines on the gold badge - has been fixed

Answer (score 52):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

## Problem: A generic close reason for most users for most questions

I don't always use my account when browsing Stack Overflow, so this message was my first introduction to the new post notices:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).
>
> ---
>
> Want to improve this question? [Update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11304895/edit) so it's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

[example question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304895/6083675)

[image]

This was very confusing to me, because it wasn't really obvious why the question was closed. Did the close voters just not agree on a reason so none was shown?

The answer is *no*, it was just one of the "site specific" close reasons like for software recommendation questions. (The other close reasons, like "too broad", or whatever it's called, give some information.)

The detailed information is only shown to the question author and users with 3k+ rep. That leaves 99% of users in the dark. There's not even some trick (short of getting 3k+ rep or switching to the app/API) to get the exact close reason, as the revision history says nothing more.

<sub>(Everyone can still see who voted to close the question in the revision history, even though this is almost always less useful than the close reason itself.)</sub>

Why was the close reason not shown to me? Was I supposed to go click on the "on-topic" link (not even the link where you think the relevant information would be), research, and deduce what close reason should have been shown? How does this help the people who want an answer to the question?

New users sometimes complain about the closing on Stack Overflow being arbitrary — but that was even before this change. Now I expect this to be an even more frequent complaint, one that I sympathize with.

This also isn't helping future close voters to learn what reason to use.

Please change it back so that everyone can see why exactly a question was closed.

---

Despite being declined, it looks like [this is actually being fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396597/6083675)? Moderators should be able to decide what gets shown to each group of users:

[image: create new close reason dialog]

Most (if not all) moderators will be good with putting close information back into the banner, and I expect that Stack Overflow will do it soon (probably after the community discusses what to put there).
I’m not sure how fast we’ll see this feature on sites outside Stack Overflow though.

Comment: I often suggest that new users take a look at questions that were and were not well received to see learn what is expected of them here. Without this explanatory info, that kind of learning (which is how I learned to be a useful contributor here) would be a lot harder

Comment: At least a link on "off-topic" would be in order.

Comment: Declined: there are legitimate reasons to show close reasons for the public view. However, we are not going to do so at this time. The vast majority of users who will view these (without privileges to reopen) are not going to be acting on it. And we have plans to change the close workflow very soon in ways that will hopefully be more effective in achieving our objectives than this change will. We will be concentrating our efforts there.

Comment: Yeah, so the difficulty is that mods can’t *edit* existing close reasons, they can only create new ones. This is because all the existing post notices will change to the edited text, so in most cases, it’s better to start over for anything short of minor edits. So, to add this info, mods either need to create new reasons or ask a CM to add the new field content. As you might expect, even if there’s only an average of two per site, that’s around 350 reasons to edit. 

Answer (score 46):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> Completion notes: we addressed point #2 below (now "spam and non-answer activity") as well as point #4 (now "you have enough reputation to answer"). More discussion on this in the comments; summary is: this *should* be used for questions that have had an unusual level of unwanted activity; that it's misused is not something we can readily solve with copy changes. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/)

Please consider revising the Protected banner to more closely match the meaning of the words that used to be there. Currently, this banner:

[image: Screenshot of banner]

> Highly active question. Since you have [insert your reputation here if over 10 earned on the site] reputation, you can answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam activity. Learn more.

Only covers one use of the "protected" banner: situations where it was automatically added due to a number of recent answers being added, with some being deleted. This wording is problematic in that it seems exclusionary where the other uses of the feature are concerned:

1. A question is not necessarily "highly active" (or active at all) while the banner is up. The banner doesn't automatically get removed after some period of inactivity, so at best this wording is only temporarily accurate.
2. A question can be protected pretty much at any time after the question has been posted. A question could receive 15 answers the day it was asked, and then someone could come by and protect it after one or two users post spam posts six years later. Not exactly "active", considering the actual activity was two posts that never should have occurred in the first place. In fact, I think the automated protection mechanism for deleted answers doesn't care about how closely a series of deleted answers were posted... it just counts the total # of spam/rude deleted answers (correct me if I'm wrong).
3. A question can be protected without any activity at all. Sure, this is probably not the ideal use for it (and a lot of the use of protection is intended to be temporary, after all), but it often happens that I come across a question with, say, 30 answers, and the last activity was 5 months ago by a then-1-rep user, but the answer is low quality/shouldn't have been added. Well, I will often protect such questions to prevent other unnecessary/low-quality answers from being added. But is the question currently active/highly active? No, not really.
4. Finally, the wording *assumes* the question is one I can answer:

   > You can answer this question.

   I actually found the screenshot for this answer on a Vim question. I have never used Vim, so I definitely can't answer that question. It would be better to say "may" instead of "can", at least. But I'd also suggest saying, instead of "since you have X reputation" (where X is your actual reputation), just say "since you have earned more than 10 reputation". The live shot at how much reputation is kinda neat, but it's unnecessary since we can see how much reputation we have in the top bar at all times, and the way it's written makes it kind of confusing (for example: "does the site expect me to be able to answer a given question *just based on my high reputation?!*").

---

Also, the new banner has no indication that it is related to the "protected" privilege. Maybe a good solution to points 1 thru 3 above would be to simply change "**Highly active**" to "**Protected**"?

Comment: I agree on point 4. Perhaps a slightly better wording is "You can post an answer", as in "you are allowed to", as opposed to "you have the knowledge to do it".

Comment: It would also be less confusing if it said "since you have at least [limit] reputation".

Comment: @VLAZ The typical wording to avoid that confusion is to replace "can" with "may". "Can" implies ability (ambiguous) whereas "may" implies permission/authorization.

Comment: I find 4. particularly odd. It doesn't even convey you need at least some Y rep, but reads like there is something special about the exact 5 digit number (in our case).

Comment: Why even show this at all to users above the threshold? _"You are allowed to do a thing that you are always allowed to do."_

Comment: There are several different triggers for Protect status, but they all presume a certain, unusual, level of activity: either a high number of new-user answers in a short time, or new-user answers that necessitated deletion over a longer period. #3 is... Something I'd rather folks stopped doing; it's sometimes appropriate (the question you describe *is* highly active), but I've seen folks do it on questions with few or *no* answers, which is bunk. #4 we should probably address; this doesn't read correctly. WRT the privilege: the "learn more" link at the end links directly to the privilege page.

Comment: @Shog9 A good prereq to handle bunk #3 cases could be 'if no recent activity, the Q has to have over 10 answers already'. Or give 10k users the ability to cast delete votes on answers... people are using it as a tool to stop bad answers because they don't have a better tool to handle those answers. I have some success with users self-deleting such answers when I downvote/comment, but it's just as likely I get a proverbial bird flipped at me and a revenge downvote to go along (or someone just not understanding how their answer repeats existing content [or doesn't address the question]).

Comment: This banner should also be shown *near the answer box*. I keep seeing this banner when linked from a SERP to a question I want to just read. There's no reason to tell me so prominently I can answer the question when I just want to read it.

Comment: @pkamb While that does make sense, it also makes sense to tell you before you spend any time scrolling.

Comment: I agree with @pkamb, I came here because I'm starting to get annoyed with this message telling me what I can do. I'm well aware of how the site works and what abilities are afforded to me by my reputation. Even just a dismiss button would be a big help (even better if it was a permanent "never show" setting)

Comment: [Remove or make “Highly active question” post notice less visible / annoying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337708/remove-or-make-highly-active-question-post-notice-less-visible-annoying/337752)

Comment: Addressed: #2 (now "spam and non-answer activity") #4 (now "you have enough reputation to answer"). Marking this complete, because - as I said in my previous comment - "highly active" is the goal here; in the same way that it's possible to close questions for the wrong reason, it's possible to misuse protect.

Answer (score 38):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Link text should say what it links to. Generic "read more" and "here" links are considered bad practice and especially [harm accessibility](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text) (users of screen readers rely heavily on link text).

> **Closed.** This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

The "Learn more" link is confusing. Does it explain what's on-topic and off-topic? Does it explain why closed questions don't accept answers?

Considering it links to [closed-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), the text should be *"Learn more about closed questions"* or something like this.

> **Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege.** [Edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/337013/edit) to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Closed 4 hours ago by Foo, Bar, Baz.

"Learn more" strikes again. This time it links to [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so the text should be something like *"Learn more about what is on-topic"*.

Alternatively, links can be placed naturally, for example:

> **Closed.** This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is [not currently accepting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).
>
> **Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege.** [Edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/337013/edit) to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the [shortest code necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.

Comment: Agreed - [I suggested the same during the previous feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332516/398063).

Comment: "Learn more" goes directly against WebAIM's accessibility guidelines: https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text

Comment: @AndrewMyers Thanks for the link, added it to the post.

Comment: Thanks the this feedback. Based on your suggestion we have removed almost every single _Learn more_ link from the notice language, moving the help links to other words in the notice.

Answer (score 34):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A couple days ago I found [a post where two close reasons were listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578510/why-am-i-getting-a-close-parenthesis-exeption-in-symfony-4):

> [image: post notice with two close reasons]

How are these cases handled with the new post notices? The part of the new post notice reserved for this doesn't seem to adjust to this scenario.

Sadly, it seems I am on the **B** group, so I can't just visit the question to check it out for myself.

But from the comments to this answer it appears that users below 3k reputation see this:

> [image: new post notice multiple close reasons]

And users with the close vote privilege see it like this:

> [image]

Comment: I'm in group A, so a link would help and I can tell you

Comment: I didn't want to bring undue attention to the question, but there you go. Link included.

Comment: @yivi Badly, it handles them badly

Comment: Handles them as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxxG.png

Comment: Im in group A here you go => https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbkNE.png . Please send help.

Comment: @DragandDrop That's interesting, I see them as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjIWC.png (and I have CV priv). So you can see *more* ***without*** the CV privilege for posts with multiple OT reasons

Comment: Yes, same with Nick A. That's a bit strange.

Comment: @Nick Do you have more than 3k on SO?

Comment: Yes, and the other screenshot users do not

Comment: I'll update accordingly. Thanks @Nick.

Comment: So there is 2 group: OP, <3k, >3k, >10k, etc.., and the group B

Comment: @NickA, thats a bug report right there ;)

Comment: My biggest bone with this is that I don't immediately see why it is off-topic. What should I focus my editing on to make it on-topic again?

Comment: This is fixed. When there are multiple close reasons (with each receiving at least two votes or with a gold/mod vote) then they are all listed.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Related to the issue in this post, might you please check out the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59120972) (being discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391818/), by the OP who is confused at the lack of an off-topic reason)? It seems pretty likely to have been closed due to being an off-site resource request, but no reason is displayed in the banner. I think it's either a bug, or a pretty odd coincidence (no two close votes agreed on a reason), or it was closed via a custom reason whose comment got deleted (also odd).

Comment: @CertainPerformance I reported that issue – a bug, IMO – [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337914/271271). It was marked as [tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 34):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The names of people who have voted to delete/recommended deletion from review aren't shown when an answer has been deleted.

There is a trailing `"by ."` which is confusing. I'm unsure if names are supposed to be removed, the direction I thought we were heading in, and therefore the *by* is redundant, or the names are missing.

[image]

> This post is hidden. This post was deleted from review last year by . Learn more.

[Example SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48730819)

Comment: We are now showing the close date on all close notices (and the close users if it is relevant for you based on your privileges)

Comment: Thanks for feeding back

Answer (score 32):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In other places of the site you make use of the [serial comma (Oxford comma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), for the sake of consistency can we make use of it when listing the people who have closed the question too.

From:

> Closed 25 months ago by Yaakov Ellis, Jon Ericson and Shog9

To:

> Closed 25 months ago by Yaakov Ellis, Jon Ericson, and Shog9

Comment: Yeah. So...that is kind of my fault. I actually edited the image for this one in my dev console in order to get some more names in the list (since all of my testing just had my name by itself). And then I left out the Oxford comma (also the reason why you don't see mod diamonds by our names). 

So the good news is that the bug is in the screenshot and not in the site, and the Oxford comma is still firmly in place. The bad news is that I got caught. I'll put in a new image shortly. And kudos to you for spotting this.

Comment: @YaakovEllis after adopting the Oxford comma, anything else just stands out like a sore thumb.

Comment: Or remove the comma everywhere, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: *Update*: I have removed the offending image, and have put in a duplicate post notice that meets this requirement

Comment: @YaakovEllis The new image also got the second sentence "If these questions don't resolve your question, ask a new one" removed. Was this on purpose? Because like Glorfindel suggested, it should tell the OP to edit the question if it doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: @Tom I took the new screenshot off the site an hour ago, so that is what is live.

Comment: If you're going to add that comma, you might as well leave out *and*. That prevents opponents/proponents of the Oxford comma from arguing as well ;-)

Answer (score 28):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Another small suggestion: Don't show the large "This post is hidden" notice on other users' deleted posts.

[image: pic]

This notice is indeed useful for a hapless newcomer who can't understand what a red background on their post means.

But for a 10k+ user looking at a long chain of deleted answers, this seems to be unnecessarily visually cluttering.

I suggest only showing this prominent notice to the user who owns the deleted post. For other users, a small non-highlighed disclaimer below the post (exactly how it looked before the update) is enough.

---

Alternatively, show this notice only to users with less than 10k rep. (as suggested by @NathanOliver)

Comment: *I suggest only showing this prominent notice to the user who owns the deleted post* Can we change that to *I suggest only showing this prominent notice to the user who owns the deleted post if they have less than 10K rep*?

Comment: This is a more specific version of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337039/361484 So this will be status declined as well probably.

Comment: @Luuklag I think that one is different. It suggests to hide the *"Visible to %user_category%"* part of some notices, while I suggest hiding a specific notice entirely.

Comment: While I agree the banner is significantly more visually obvious than what's needed, the banner does contain useful information, which should be presented somewhere. The useful information is who, or what, deleted the post and when it was deleted. The rest of the information that's provided is completely useless, except to someone seeing a deleted post for the first time. Do you have a suggestion for how the useful information should be displayed?

Comment: @Makyen Before the update, we used to have small *"deleted by %username%"* notices below deleted posts. In the answer, I suggested reverting to that: *"For other users, a small non-highlighed disclaimer below the post (exactly how it looked before the update) is enough."*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are going for consistent messaging for all cases and are going to keep the new deleted notice on top of the post, as-is.

Comment: @Makyen It was fine how it was before :(

Answer (score 26):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The bounty period is not displayed in hours anymore if it ends in less than one day:

[image]

I see two problems:

- It is unclear: Does it mean “no time left” or “less than one day left”? Apparently it is the latter, but that is not obvious.
- Important information is missing: For a possible answerer it matters whether there is 1 minute or 23 hours left to post an answer (which is eligible for the bounty).

Here is an example of how it looked before (the remaining time was displayed in hours if less than one day, and in minutes if less than one hour):

[image]

I suggest to display a more precise remaining time again.

Comment: This is now fixed

Comment: @Yaakov I can't repro this personally because I'm not seeing the new notices, but [this screenshot on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391083) suggests there are some lingering text-formatting issues here, causing a very ungrammatical string to be displayed. Can you check this, please? How did that leading "in" get there?

Comment: @CodyGray lingering text-formatting issues are fixed

Comment: Confirmed, I see *“The bounty expires in 6 hours.”* now.

Answer (score 24):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In my opinion the below notice is somewhat unclear *what* it is referring to. I understand that it is only the second half below the horizontal rule but I feel like it could do with being made a bit clearer.

> Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege

Also the icon that is used seems a bit odd to me but I wouldn't know a better choice or even if one is even necessary.

Comment: [agreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow#comment1118639_337013) (although not the icon bit, that makes sense to me)

Comment: Indeed. I find "private feedback for you" even stranger. What is private feedback for me? Everything? Only the blob of text that follows? It's so robotic, I would make that more personal. "**The following is for your eyes only**: unicorns, rainbows, lost keys".

Comment: Agreed, this is *very* unclear/misleading.  When I first saw this text today, I thought it was saying that the duplicate question I just closed was only going to be visible to the author and people with open/close privilege.  I thought, "wait, we're hiding duplicates now?"

Comment: I thought it's referring to the whole question, as in "This question is removed from the front page now"?

Comment: we have updated the layout of the bottom to hopefully make this distinction clearer

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks, but personally I don't see much improvement. The misleading eye icon is still there. The text doesn't specify what is visible only to 3k. If you would like to keep that sentence there, can it say that the names of people who voted are shown only to users >3k? And can you remove the eye icon? Comparing it to the deleted post banner one can really get the idea this icon means the whole post is hidden.

Comment: I would definitely challenge the [tag:status-completed] on this. It was definitely [status:changed-in-some-way] but the change doesn't really fix the problem at all. I understand now that the text means "the text in the blue box below the horizontal rule" but it still doesn't say anything like that. It took me approx a week (admittedly, very low intensity effort) to figure it out, and I don't see how this changes the required amount of effort really.

Answer (score 23):

No bug report, no rant, just a simple:

**Thank you**.

(plus suggestions how to continue from here, see further below)

Seriously, it is great to see that Stack Exchange Inc. actually did put in serious efforts to improve this core aspect of quality control. And albeit many "quality control users" complained for years about lack of support, within a few days, there is plenty of helpful, precise feedback.

So, please continue on this path! And note: even in the midst of that storm that is shaking the whole community, the community users are **obviously** willing to **work with you**.

And my direct feedback regarding the UI itself: it really looks/feels "fresh", and I hope that it won't take long to incorporate the reasonable feedback, and to roll this change permanently.

Then, to underline what you already mentioned: this goes **way** beyond "just the close reasons". Close reasons relate to queues, and most importantly: follow up actions. And oh boy, there is [work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376364/how-to-fix-triage) waiting for you. So, what you seriously need to look into:

- The overall workflow. As explained in the aforementioned link: the *triage* queue on SO is a nightmare. Fix that.
- One way to get there: improved education. You could prepare an education package that includes 50 or 100 questions for people to train with. Hand selected questions, with manually written explanations for each one of them!

The one thing I ask you folks to remember: **stay agile**! Don't wait too long in order to release the *perfect* thing. Rather roll early, but be around to constantly fix bugs and improve features frequently!

Comment: Thanks you very much! [My response](https://twitter.com/Yaakov/status/1190969500079923200)

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thank you very much. Your tweets are truly inspiring, I am really glad that you liked my answer here, and I really appreciate you took the time to respond like that!

Comment: I'm tardy, but I also wanted to say thanks for this answer @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica. I echo the sentiments Yaakov linked. <3

Answer (score 22):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

We used to flag "this post is not written in English on English Stack Overflow" as ["unclear what you're asking."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)

The new verbiage doesn't really allow for that interpretation:

> **Needs details or clarity**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add
> additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
> currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
> the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Not sure if we want to touch this/what we should do here.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to always do a custom close reason for non-English posts.  "Unclear what you're asking" was a bit ambiguous anyway.

Comment: The issue is that you can't do a custom close flag. And the last time someone did generic moderator flags, they were [declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390015/why-were-my-wrong-language-flags-declined) which makes sense (the community should be able to handle it without mod intervention).

Comment: You can do a custom close reason under "Off-topic" > "Other"

Comment: I think that's a 3k (or maybe 10k) rep thing. I can't flag for that with the 15 rep benefit.

Comment: Re *"written in not-English"*: Did it really say that? Or was it *"not written in English"*? Or *"written in not English"*? *"written in non-English"*?

Comment: @yhyrcanus oh you're right, I'm talking about close votes, but you're talking about flags

Comment: _Declined_: we think that this can now be tagged as "needs details or clarity". Alternatively, a custom close reason can be used: "I'm voting to close this question because it is not in English".

Comment: @YaakovEllis "we think that this can now be tagged as "needs detail or clarity"". The question may be written in flawless Italian with an MCVE, research, links to related questions, and a witty pun, but it's still in Italian, not English. I'm not being snarky, but pointing out the irony given that the text described is inaccurate.

Comment: @JonHarper "Clarity: the quality of being coherent and intelligible." I think that if it is written in the wrong language for the site, it is most definitely lacking in clarity (even if it is perfectly written in whatever language).

Answer (score 21):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When doing a closing vote for a duplicate, there was a comment added, such as *"Possible duplicate of Link-To-the-Dupe"*.
If the question was closed for a dupe, this comment was removed.

With the new post notice system the comments are changed to : *"Does this answer your question? Link-To-the-Dupe"*.
When the question is closed, the comment remains

Comment: Thanks, we just noticed that as well.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337019/51 above as well

Comment: The logic for this bug was fixed within a day of when it was reported. Marking it as completed now since I finally got around to fixing up the data, and deleting those comments that should have been auto-deleted.

Comment: Thank you @YaakovEllis

Answer (score 18):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[image: This post is hidden. This post was deleted from review 2 years ago by . Learn more.]

> This post is hidden. This post was deleted from review 2 years ago by . Learn more.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46930006/1265393
>
> **FIXED:**
>
> This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review 2 years ago by User1, User2, User3, User4. Learn more.

Two things:

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **"deleted from review"** is awkward phrasing. "Deleted via Review" or "Deleted as a result of the Review process" or similar would be better. Hopefully with a hyperlink to the Review itself.
2. <strike>deleted "by ." - name missing for some reason?</strike> [DUPLICATE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337063#337063)

another:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> This post is hidden. This post was deleted and converted to a comment review 7 years ago by Brad Larson♦. Learn more.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9818900/1265393
>
> **FIXED:**
>
> This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted and converted to a comment 7 years ago by Brad Larson♦. Learn more.

- **"converted to a comment review"** ...? Should be "converted to a comment"?

---

NEW:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)-ish [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> This **post** is hidden. This **post** was deleted 4 years ago by the post author. Learn more.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241248/1265393

Note that in the 2 above original bugs, your fixes changed "post" to "answer" in the 2nd part of the question. But that change didn't happen in other notices such as the new one above. The originals also both have "post" AND "answer" in the same notice.

Comment: Probably meant to be "reviewed 7 years ago". I would say it's a typo.

Comment: Both issues raised here have been fixed

Comment: @YaakovEllis great, thanks! I added a related tweak to the bottom re: "post" vs. "answer".

Comment: All notices are now internally consistent with use of post/answer (some of the notices are reused for questions and answers - thus the usage of "post")

Answer (score 16):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

I like the idea of rephrasing the close types, but I really think you should bring back the **"Too-broad"** closure type. It has been replaced with "Need more focus", which to me means something different than too-broad. The message in the notice says:
[image]

At the same time the message when closing he question says:
[image]

Here are my problems with it:

1. Why do people who vote to close see more explanation than is displayed in the notice?
2. Why is the "How to ask" link not in the notice?
3. Why does it say "Needs more focus" in one place and "needs to be more focused" in the other? There is slight, but significant difference in my opinion.
4. What does it exactly mean that the question needs to be more focused? Take for example this question [Please Help I need Your Experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612817/please-help-i-need-your-experience) [Screenshot for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVn6V.png)
   How could anyone edit it be more focused? What should I focus on when editing this? For me this is not a real question. It doesn't ask any question, it is just begging for help and free codez.
   If I wanted to close this question I would hesitate to use this closure type.

The text IMHO is even less welcoming than before. I would suggest we improve the blue notice along the lines of:

> **On-hold.** This question is not about any specific problem. It must be edited before it can accept more answers.
>
> ---
>
> **Want to improve this question?** [Edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/337071/edit), so it focuses on a single problem only. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about asking good questions.

Comment: A small note: I think the current text should say: "It is currently not accepting answers." instead of "It is not currently accepting answers.". I believe it sounds more correct in English.

Comment: Per the suggestion in your comment, the latter (the current wording) sounds more natural to me than the former.

Comment: IMO, this answer, unfortunately, includes too many different issues, rather than focusing individually on the three (or four) issues which you are addressing. It would have been better to have one answer which focused on the change to using only "closed", rather than "on hold", a separate question addressing some of your nubmered wording issues and then either an additional answer (or two) which focused on your request/proposal to switch back to using "too broad" and "unclear". Separating them into different answers would have made your issues more clear and allowed focused discussion.

Answer (score 16):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

When a question is closed for a typographical error, the display message stating so (that it is closed due to a typographical error) is only displayed to those with close/open privileges:
[image]

If, however, you don't have those privileges you get this message:

[image]

This asks the user to update the question to make it on-topic. If the question, however, is closed due to typographical reasons then it can't be made on-topic. Therefore users without the close/reopen privilege shouldn't really be asked to try to improve it; as it can't be.

Comment: We will be addressing this as part of the upcoming Close UX project

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

On mobile the gold badge is not displayed properly on duplicate questions closed with a hammer.

[image]

Comment: I actually sort of noticed that too, but didn't think anything of it.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This doesn't sound good:

> [image]

1. What's "..."? Clicking <kbd>(more)</kbd> doesn't show anything. So, the question is a duplicate of what? IMO, the "of..." is useless.
2. Should "Duplicate" start with capital?

Comment: Can you please leave a link to the question?

Comment: @YaakovEllis it appears groups were switched and I no longer see the new UI. However, if you go to [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen), you will (hopefully) reproduce that.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Queued...

Comment: [More] shows the options beneath. Nothing changed there. I have however added in the off topic reasons and their descriptions in a way that is hopefully a bit clearer. In this case "Duplicate of..." is the name of the off-topic category, and is appearing as intended.

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

#### Questions closed as "off-site resource request" do not show the reason they were closed. They say only "off-topic".

- [Link to example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534119/is-there-any-open-source-mocking-framework-resembling-typemock)
- Image of question with post notice that says only "off-topic":
  [image: Question closed as a resource request showing only "off topic" as the reason]

  ---
- [SE API query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#ids=1534119&filter=!Frv9VbqjvQr7DLG6A3Qmkpozvw&site=stackoverflow&run=true): To verify the close reason, look at the `description` in the `closed_details`. You actually have to look through the HTML, but that HTML renders as:

  > This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
  >
  > "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it." – Machavity, JL2210, Makyen, tripleee, Vadim Kotov

- All of the other off-topic reasons state which reason it is in the post notice, except custom reasons. So, I'm assuming that the intent is to have this reason displayed in the post notice.

Comment: The API is still pulling the v1 reasons. This will be more consistent once the changes roll out network-wide

Comment: @YaakovEllis The issue isn't that the SE API is still providing the V1 reasons. The issue is that the new notices don't say why the post was closed, other than just "off-topic". This is a reduction in information provided to the OP, and is inconsistent with other notices. The "off-site resource" close reason is the only current, stock, off-topic reason for which the new post notices don't say the actual off-topic reason. The SE API info is in this answer because it's the only current way for someone to determine the actual reason the question was closed, not because the SE API should change.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - The network wide roll out did not improve the situation. Off topic (sub topic) is still simply referred to as Off topic with no reason given.

Comment: If you have more concerns about this, please open a new question. This one is a bit dated and I would like to move the conversation elsewhere

Comment: I have just noticed this issue, having collaborated with SO CVR to close it, and the OP is now asking why the question was closed. The old notices would have notified of the close reason(s).

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A gold badge holder isn't "some community members":

[image]

This could possible be:

[image]

Or even better, "A **trusted** community member".

Comment: A trusted user is a user with over 20k reputation. You do not need to be over 20k to be a gold badger (although it certainly helps). "A community member" is good enough, unless a someone can provide nice, easily understood copy to explain "a gold badger".

Comment: Fixed. The language now changes based on whether there is one closing users or more than one closing user.

Answer (score 12):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Since you will be rolling this out network wide and you've said:

> We feel that in order to properly evaluate the changes to
>   presentation, language and functionality, the changes need to be seen
>   in the context of the site, by users who encounter them through normal
>   site usage.

Will you be doing a similar test period for sites other than Stack Overflow? For example, the automatic comments for duplicates ("Does this answer your question? [link]") doesn't really make much sense on [Code-Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) due to it not being a standard Q&A site. There's also been [talk about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow?page=1&tab=votes#comment1118670_337023) how the phrasing of some notices would be inaccurate on other sites.

If you aren't, will sites at least be able to edit the phrasing of notices that don't make as much sense in the context of their sites?

Comment: We are not planning a wider test before releasing to the entire network. And we don't have definite plans at this time to allow customization of notice language on a per-site basis (though we are considering variations on this). We will take this feedback into account.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Since you can obviously rollout on just SO, is it possible to hold off on implementing it across all sites until you're sure that it won't have negative effects on other sites?

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new version of the bounty notification doesn't provide a specific start and end date when hovering over the "vague" expiring information, like "tomorrow". The old message provided it:

[image: Old version]

But the new one only provides the ending date when hovering over the **bounty amount**, but not for the word "tomorrow".

[image: New version]

I guess it is a bug, that the popup now shows on hovering over the bounty value, but if that was done on purpose, then I would like to request the feature to do that on the usual spot instead. It is much more intuitive to do it there and matches the usual behaviour on SE sites (hovering dates or similar words provide a detailed timestamp).

Comment: Good catch. Date hover will move to the _time left_.

Comment: This is now fixed. Hover on _time left_ and you should now see the end date of the bounty.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thank you for the fix. One question though, why doesn't it also include the start time anymore?

Comment: The expanded hover tool tip that was used to show both start and end dates is not included in our design system [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/popovers#content). And as the start date is not essential information here, not going to add it back in with new popovers in Stacks.

Answer (score 11):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

## Clarify that duplicate questions are closed as well.

Duplicate questions are not just already having answers elsewhere already, they also have the "closed" status that means they're not accepting answers any more. The new post notice doesn't mention that anywhere, except in the view for close-voters and authors, and even then only in the last sentence. Similarly, [it doesn't mention that it's still editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015/183280) either.

The wording of the message "*Some community members have associated your post with similar questions.*" suggests that it's a mere association, like a "see also these related questions".

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As a power user with close/reopen privileges, I would expect to always see the details of the closure on all closed questions. However, this is not the case <s>on my own closed questions</s> for old (deactivated) close reasons!

I am especially concerned about not even being able to view the date of closure, like on [this old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515977/does-the-arguments-object-leak). It just shows up like this:

> [image: question screenshot]

Comment: I imagine you already know, but it was closed as "non constructive", which is not a part of the currently active close reasons. I guess this is not hidden to you because you are the question author, but because support for this legacy close-reasons has not been implemented (yet?).

Comment: @yivi Tbh I forgot about the "non constructive" close reason, thanks for reminding me! I knew the text looked unfamiliar, but I thought it was because it was the "author view". So it's good that the bug might occur only on inactive close reasons and it works as expected on contemporary closures, but imo it's a bug nonetheless.

Comment: Of course, not disagreeing in that it's a bug. Only trying to get the precise details for the bug. It's not about _who_ sees the post notice, but about the _close reason_ for the post notice.

Comment: @yivi So you can confirm that the questions looks the same for you as a non-author? Good to know.

Comment: I saw it like that yesterday... now for some reason I've been pushed to the *B* group, again. So I have to rely on my memory.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed caused by issues with legacy reasons not always having the data in the place that we are expecting it to be (or we weren't recording it in a reliable way). That said, I have added this to the list of things to look into

Comment: @YaakovEllis Close votes were not recorded in the past? And not even the timestamp of the closure?

Comment: They were recorded, but the ways in which some types of data was recorded has changed over time, as the tooling has changed. We always try to catch up the legacy data into the new structures when this happens. But sometimes things can be missed. In any event, it requires some attention.

Comment: We are now showing the close dates for all close notices, to all users.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[One of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/1983854) is protected. This is what I see when I open it:

> [image]

That is, I see the banner:

> Highly active question. You have enough reputation to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity. [Learn more.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

1. I don't think it makes much sense to indicate to me, the OP, that I have enough reputation to answer my own question. While it is important to notify a OP that they *cannot* answer it, I think that indicating that they *can* does not add value.
2. Once you've seen this banner several times, it would be useful allowing to dismiss it or leave it on the footer. It takes important space when it is no longer relevant.

Comment: The banner should be shown only to those, who do NOT have such privileges ( and may be to author and moderators). For other users the information is irrelevant and should be hidden.

Comment: The _Highly Active Question_ banner is now only shown to users who either do not have enough rep to answer (10 earned rep), or who have enough rep to unprotect (15K earned rep). Users who are in between (and thus are able to answer, but can't do anything about the protected status) are no longer shown this banner.

Comment: @Yaakov thank you for the announcement, but I don't think this is marking as complete neither of the two of the points of my feature request.

Comment: @ferdorqui would it be better if I mark it as declined? We are not going to turn it off for the poster who has enough rep to unprotect it. And we are not going to allow you to dismiss it permanently at this point. So in that sense it is declined. However, I feel that the main usability issue is (in my opinion) showing unactionable notices to people. And that is taken care of now.

Answer (score 10):

When a post is closed due to both being "unclear" and "too broad" close votes, show a custom message that covers both.  Eg "too broad" could be due to the post being "unclear" about what the detailed problem is.

Answer (score 10):

> During our initial launch period the new post notices (and all related changes) are being shown to 50% of users. There is **no easy way to switch** between the group of users seeing old or new notices. **If there are things about the new notices that you dislike, please let us know** in a respectful and constructive way. We are happy to receive and take all feedback into consideration.

Over a dozen answers thus far have found an "old versus new" shortcoming, with one simply being grammatical or punctuation. Some users can rely on their socks (and multiple tabs) to make side by side comparisons, most users can not.

It's unfortunate that a small group of users (possibly > 10K, or at least the moderators) can't see ***both*** old and new (one above the other) with *radio buttons* beside each - that way if the new version is *wrong* in some way (not a suitable manner to present the older information) they can click the radio button next to the old version; indicating a failure of the newer version.

It's more difficult to say what you don't like about the new notices if you can't compare them directly with the older ones. **Alternatively this question could show before and after examples for each instance**.

**If** both old and new were intended to be identical I can see having "**A** / **B**" groups but when you're serving two different *pills* you end up providing the *real thing* to one group and a *placebo* to the other.

This could lead to one group commenting, flagging, reopening, etc. based on what they see while the other group must rely on information later found to be incomplete or deficient in some way.

It's unfortunate that "there is no easy way".

Generally one would use "**A** / **B**" to determine which group has a better result, or if there was no difference. Here you are asking group "**B**" to compare the new experience with how it used to be based on memory.

Group "**A**" ends up with no say in the matter and group "**B**" has nothing to compare to; while the moderators may not know which group the person is in, or if they do they still end up with additional deciphering and fluidly changing extra work. Much like flags dropped on edited posts, where different people see different versions of the same thing.

Comment: Rather than blind A/B groups, I think testing this would have been better served by trialing it as an optional beta feature. Maybe opting-in users randomly to begin with, but letting everyone turn it on and off for the duration of the trial.

Comment: Yes, some users seeing the *new* banner haven't seen that particular version of the old one (either would be *new* to them);  or recently / frequently enough to know what is to be compared. Group "A" is completely blind and group "B" is double blind (if they have no socks). --- If Yaakov's only *question* was "will this result in better or worse flagging and comments along with correct reopens" then A/B could work, but a comparison is being asked for (to something that isn't available).

Comment: Apparently [people are being moved between **A** and **B** groups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337038#comment1119319_337013) rather than being stuck in a single group (and having no opinion); that doesn't resolve *this* answer/comment/observation but it does alter it, but I'm not bumping (yet, anyways).

Answer (score 10):

This is in regards to the OP being able to see who closed the question.  Do we really want to do this?  It gives people that might be upset that their question is closed a convenient outlet for misdirected hostility. If we want to be nice and welcoming we should apply that equally and hide this information from the OP unless they also have Close Vote privileges.

This will make the close voters lives easier as they will be a lot less likely to be targeted by revenge votes or rude/abusive comments.  If the OP wants someone to badger, they can leave a generic comment or go to meta.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, it seems like this new version makes that information less visible than before. Or are you suggesting that they go further and remove that information altogether?

Comment: @divibisan I'm suggesting that they make it more restrictive and only show the close voters to the OP if they can cast close votes themselves.  Right now people with cv-privs and the OP can see the close voters.  To me I don't see a reason why a <3K rep user needs that information.  There is nothing gained by giving it to them and it opens the potential for targeting of those people.

Comment: If the closure was done by a single user (i.e. dup-hammer or moderator), there is something gained by showing that username. In that case, in a comment on the question, anyone can `@ping` the user who closed. In some cases, that's valuable. In other cases, it's detrimental. If the benefit outweighs the detriment is debatable. However, it is something that's enabled by showing the user who unilaterally closed the question. I agree it's not useful to show a list of multiple close-voters. I've several times seen OPs trying to ping those close-voters from comments, which, of course, doesn't work.

Comment: Couldn't they see that under the old system anyway?

Comment: @Chipster They could.  Now the SO seems to be okay with limiting the information, I'm asking for a little more limiting to happen.

Answer (score 10):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

You guys are looking into updating the close reasons? Thank you. Thank you thank you thank you.

I cannot tell you how many different ways I have asked for this in the past.

The close reasons are tightly coupled with the topicality of the sites, so it is certainly a tough subject to approach. They are also closely related to welcoming, and so any improvement there will be a drastic increase in community health.

The main issue with the current set of close reasons is that they didn't scale well. While they worked well enough at first, the sheer volume of question *types* that have been generated did not match the existing set of close reasons.

**There needs to be more close reasons.**

Simply tweaking the wording will make some small progress, but expanding the list will have a much greater impact. Close reasons with multiple sentences are not only confusing to many users, but also leave the door open to interpretation which causes strife in the community.

If there are to be multiple sentences in a close reason, then only the first should define the closure; the rest could still be used for help material, but should not be used for clarification.

**Limit close reasons to one closure type.**

Allowing close reasons to cast a net whereby they close multiple types of questions at once creates unease and friction. New users are unsure what exact aspect they violated, and veterans will argue over which aspect of the net was invalid for use.

Comment: Since this was downvoted, I am curios, I assume it would be because someone thinks it is a bad idea to limit closure reasons to one type or expand the list. I would rather be that I was personally downvoted ;) since that would not be reflective on the content, but I am sure that isn't the case. Just in case, in comments below, I would like to see an anonymous poll if you don't mind taking part (downvoters or upvoters). There will be 4 comments available to vote on to express agreement or disagreement with the main two aspects shown here.

Comment: I would like to see more close reasons.

Comment: I do not want to see more close reasons.

Comment: I would like to limit close reasons to one closure type.

Comment: I do not mind closure reasons covering more than one type.

Comment: I'm confused by the options

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica - Sorry, I thought they were straightforward. What aspect should I clarify?

Comment: This only concerns the new post notices and the close reason names. They're currently not looking into adding new close reasons.

Comment: @JL2210 - That's not entirely accurate, although it is true this post only addresses the current set and text.

Comment: Multiple close reasons can be confusing, but sometimes questions are all over the place that it is very hard to choose most appropriate one. It is hard to say what is the best, showing only one close reason when it may not be the best one or showing multiple ones where at least some would make sense to the OP.

Comment: I am definitely for having more granular close reasons that would ease closure process and make it more clear why the question is actually closed.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile The intent behind showing close reason(s) to the OP is to let them know why the post was closed and what they would need to do to make it on-topic, so it can be reopened. A significant problem with showing the OP only one close reason is that there may be several reasons why the question was closed, each requiring additional editing to resolve. In such cases, showing only one reason to the OP is a very poor experience for the users that try to edit their question to get it reopened. They'll resolve one problem, but have no idea there are N other issues needing attention.

Comment: Rather than creating a poll in comments you should create a new question and reference it from here

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? (And maybe it was always like this?)

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I don't see how you can "provide detailed answers" if the question is "not currently accepting answers". If a question is closed, don't show the first ("insufficient explanation") banner—or maybe only show it to people who have an answer on the post:

> Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers. Learn more.

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWslG.png); example question: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/6083675))

Comment: So... There is a post notice - "insufficient explanation" - that does double duty: on an *answer*, it means "your answer doesn't explain anything - fix it!"... But on a *question*, it means "don't post an answer *unless you include an explanation in it*". IOW, it's always referring to answers, either in the present (on answer) or future (on question). But, by adding the "Want to improve this post?" prefix, we've made it... somewhat unsuitable for questions. [What it used to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhUMM.png)

Comment: This is a case where a post was protected and then closed. The intersection of the protect notice (added by a mod) and then close notice leads to this confusion. A mod could unprotect it and it would go away. You can call it by design or wontfix, but it is an edge case that we aren't going to address at this time.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (As pointed out [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/376604/cris-luengo), the CW note was added through a mod notice)

1. Missing "Locked" post notice for the question.
2. Community Wiki notice appears to apply to just the question, when the question isn't a Community Wiki.
3. Community Wiki notice is intended to apply just to the answers, although using the term "Community Wiki" is confusing.

For locked questions which are not closed and have a "Community Wiki" notice ([search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Atrue+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano&mixed=0); [specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)), the question post notice erroneously indicates that the question itself is a Community Wiki instead of indicating that it's actually locked:

[image: A question with post notice that it's a community wiki when it's not]

### The CW notice is supposed to indicate the *answers* are intended to be edited, not the question.

The CW notice is intended to let users know that the answers can be edited, not that the question can be edited. There are several issues with the new implementation.

- The notice isn't a *post* notice, it's a *page* notice. For consistency, it needs to not be inside the question content. It should be placed at the top of the page, above the question title, or some other location to indicate it applies to the entire page, not just to the question.

  - The prior placement of the notice below the question content and spanning the entire width of the vote area and Q&A content area made it more clear that the notice applied to the answers, rather than the question.
- Calling locked questions "community wiki" is confusing. If not being called "locked" (which is what it is), then this state should be called something other than "community wiki". For posts on Stack Exchange, "community wiki" has a very specific meaning: the specific answer or question is a community wiki on which the author (or moderator) has [explicitly invited much wider participation in editing the content](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), which includes allowing users with much lower reputation, 100 on non-beta sites, free editing of those posts.
  Using "community wiki" for something significantly different than the existing definition makes it unclear what the term means.
- Locked questions are, well, locked. They can't be edited. Calling the "post" (i.e. the *question*) a community wiki is the opposite of the question's actual state (i.e. locked).

While the effect of locking a question might be somewhat like having the question and answers turned into a community wiki, the actual effect is significantly different.

Comment: The post's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/503093/timeline#history_d8fe4d2f-73c6-404c-8318-cf297c7f2229) indicates that the wiki answer note was added by a moderator.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for pointing that out. I failed to check the timeline. I'll need to look at some other questions, and probably rewrite some of what I said in this answer. From a brief look at this, I'd say the actual bug is the lack of a "Locked" notice for the question and that the positioning and wording of the "Community Wiki" notice may be an RFE, as the CW notice was probably there prior to the change in post notices. Although, I'd say that positioning the post notices at the top of the question content and clearly in the question, not the page, makes it more confusing what's intended.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if it was possible to manually switch between showing the old notices vs. showing the new post notices. I think that part of the issue here is that the old notices used to span the entire width of the display area (i.e. including the left area where the votes are), rather than be confined to within the post content. The CW notice probably made much more since when it was after the question content and spanned the width of the entire Q&A content.

Comment: On the other hand, I didn't find a note in the timeline that indicated that the question is locked. But obviously the question is locked. Did the lock and wiki labels get swapped, also in the timeline?

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Both the "This post is hidden" and "Locked" notices are missing on questions deleted as spam or rude/abusive ([example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741227)):

[image: deleted question missing both the locked and hidden notices]

The notices are, however, not missing from answers ([example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269483/ecdsa-public-key-recovery/58549908#58549908)):

[image: deleted answer with both locked and hidden]

Comment: I am looking at these questions and am seeing the hidden/locked notices

Comment: @YaakovEllis It looks like there's a difference between what you see and what I do. I just double-checked. I see neither the hidden or locked notices on the [question I linked as the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741227) ([new screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzZba.png)). I do see them on the answer I linked. I testing in a profile with all userscripts turned off, just to be sure it wasn't something the userscripts I use were affecting.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks, looking into it.

Comment: This should be fixed now. @makyen can you please confirm?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks for working on it. Unfortunately, it's not fixed for me. I still see the same as the screen-captures in this answer.

Comment: can you check again please? I think that it should be fixed now

Comment: @YaakovEllis Great! That worked. Thanks for working on it.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I'm not sure if it changed after I looked at it yesterday, or if I didn't notice. The question now has the correct post notices, but when the question is deleted as spam, the post body no longer has the text "This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the **[revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58741227/revisions)** for details." Personally, I use a userscript which provides a link to the history, but it's probably intended that the above text exist and provide the history link.

Comment: In the case where the post body is completely removed due to spam, we previously had inserted the text that you referred to. This is changing now - in this case we will be showing the relevant post notices instead (the inline text is redundant with the notices, and as it is inline text, the notices are preferable as they are clearly delineated from the post body)

Comment: @YaakovEllis The inline text is *not* redundant with the current new post notices. The new post notices don't explain why the content is *actually* hidden, not just deleted, because the new "hidden" notice looks effectively identical to the "hidden" notice that exists on *every* deleted post. Importantly, the new post notices don't contain a link to the revision history, which that text contained. I use that link, up to a few 10's of times every day, while working with SmokeDetector. I can compensate for this with a userscript, but userscripts are not something other people choose to use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We'll consider compensating for this in some way.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Please do. The link to the revision history is something I know other people use on a regular basis (i.e. many times per day). I'd note that I did find it confusing that the post didn't have content when the post notice was just the same as I see on every other deleted post.

Comment: The inline spam notice has been restored for the 10K+ rep users who can see it (in addition to the new post notices)

Comment: @YaakovEllis Looks good. Thanks for restoring that text and link.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

When a post is locked, it's not obvious that it's locked, or that you can't interact with the question, except by editing. Take [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

The new bar no longer says the word "locked" and it **de-emphasizes** that you cannot answer it.

[image: Locked?]

The bottom still says

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

The problem I have here is that we're no longer using consistent terminology. This is going to confuse new users who are going to wonder where they were told it was locked.

**Note:** While this is similar to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337272/244695), I'm focused solely on consistent terminology here, not the other issues raised.

Comment: The wording is intentional. Hopefully will be less confusing once this is fully launched.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

The new post notices still point to the [current help center articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). This reads confusing as different terminology is used there.

Is a rewrite for the help center also scheduled when this rolls out any further?

Comment: Indeed, there is a rewrite of the help center article that is just about done. Unfortunately, we dont have an easy way to include help center articles in our sampling, so we will be keeping the current version up until this is fully released to all users

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I was looking at different closed questions, and came across this one: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

[image: Closed question linked above]

It was closed as "Needs more focus" (<strike>which appears to be a legacy close reason</strike> which is the new name for the "Too broad" close reason). There are however no names and timestamp of those who closed this post and when. That information is available in the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14994391/revisions).

Edit: on mobile I see this view:

[image]

Comment: This is maybe covered/caused by the same thing as [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337026/394554).

Comment: In this case the question was only closed as "Need more focus", not multiple reasons.

Comment: Re: *"... editing this post"* - In addition it prompts users to edit the post in order to improve it, however it is locked and so cannot be edited.

Comment: @NickA I can live with that. The historical lock is the exception here, in normal cases editing would be the correct mode of action. Would be good to add though.

Comment: This is by design. The view shown to the post author or to users with close/reopen privileges are shown this info. We are hiding it for all other users as it is not relevant for them.

Comment: @Luuklag I did a little more digging: because the post is locked (aside from being closed), you are not able to reopen it, so you dont get to see the text that is relevant for users with the ability to reopen this question. If the lock was removed, you would see it. I can see it because I have mod privileges.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @YaakovEllis. Perhaps we then can go the extra mile, and just NOT show the closed notice, as it isn't relevant due to the historical lock. I'll see if that suggestion is around here, or add another answer for that.

Comment: @Luuklag you can add another answer, but I can tell you right now that it will be declined or deferred. We are not changing anything with this release regarding "what" is being shown (including multiple notice scenarios). Just changing what/where/how. So although the idea may have merit, it is out of scope for this round.

Answer (score 8):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Closing a question doesn't just affect the question's author. It also affects anyone who wishes to answer the question or edit it to make it openable. I can foresee a lot of "I don't see why this question needs to be more focused" types of comments from users who would like a question to be open and are not able to see the detailed reason why a question was closed.

Comment: @user474678, is new version suppose to be better, not worse?

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil True. I got rid of my account before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 8):

On questions which were previously called [protected questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) I can now see two notice messages. e.g. [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[image]

Why do I see both notices?
Why do I see them when I only view the question? It is the first thing I see when I open the question. Now assuming I am a low reputation user whose question was closed as duplicate of canonical post and is redirected to a *protected question*, the most prominent information I see is asking me to provide a detailed answer! The real content of the Q&A is pushed down as if it was less important.

Why can't this first message be shown where the answer button is. The answering functionality is on the very bottom of the page, where after carefully reading through all the answers I have already forgotten about the useful notice I read at the top. That is a poor UX. Can we move this information to the bottom as well? Strangely enough when I log out, I can see this information on the bottom where the answer box would normally be located as well as on top of the question.

Another point, which was also raised in SOCVR, is in regards to the reputation needed to answer. The second message tells me how much reputation I have got, and that I can answer the question. No offense, but this message makes no sense to me. I know my reputation! I know I can answer it, because I have the answer box at the bottom. At which point does this message become ridiculous? What about Jon Skeet? *"Since you have 1,140,486 reputation, you can answer this question."*

> The site just says "Since you are Jon Skeet, you can answer this question" - [Machavity](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47701660#47701660)

Comment: The `Want to improve this post` is showing because a Mod put an "Insufficient Explanation" on this post. If this is removed by a mod, then the post notice will go away. A user without enough rep will not see the second one.

Comment: We are going for consistent positioning across the board. The previous iteration of post notices were all over the place. It may take some getting used to, but we are trying to move away from having some of them at the top and some at the bottom.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Ok, I think this is new to me, but in such case why is the message sometimes at the top & bottom, and sometimes only at the top?

Comment: Yes, the rep number can be a bit much. We went back and forth on it. It is not enough to say how much rep is needed, since it is for earned rep and does not include the association bonus. We could consider rounding the number (ie show 1,140K for Jon Skeet)

Comment: The message should only be at the top of the question (in the case of a question notice) or at the top of the answer (in the case of an answer post notice). If you see otherwise, please link to it and let me know.

Comment: @YaakovEllis As I said in my post I can see it when I am not logged in. See here https://imgur.com/a/UjuEoYI

Comment: Update: we no longer show your rep number

Comment: @YaakovEllis, The banner should be shown only to those, who do NOT have such privileges. For the author and those with lock privilege it should be shown as “locked for users with not sufficient reputation”. For other users the information is irrelevant and should be hidden.

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil the banner is now [hidden for users who cannot unprotect posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340845/51).

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new text "*Some community members have associated this/your post with similar questions.*" sounds a bit funny when the OP himself voted to close or agreed with the closure. Please special-case this for self-closure or closures by the Community user.

An example by myself would be [Ways of setting/getting a textNode's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889223/ways-of-setting-getting-a-textnodes-value), although that's quite old and I'm not sure by which process I closed it. (And also I'm only seeing the "private feedback"). I couldn't find any other example to verify the latest behaviour.

Comment: Text is now special-cased when viewed by OP.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Typo/grammar/boolean logic:

> It's seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, **and more**. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

I don't think I've ever seen a question asking for books, tools, software libraries *and* more. I want it all and I want it now?

Should be changed to:

> It's seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries **or other off-site resources**. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Or you could have kept the text as it was...

Because the main reason why we don't allow these questions is not the risk of opinion-based answers - "where can I find MSDN" is a very specific question with only one possible correct answer. Rather, it is the risk of building a site where some answers are nothing but dead links.

Comment: Has been changed to: "**It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources.** This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: @Yaakov Ellis: It's now back to **" …, and more"**.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185722/where-can-i-find-androids-default-icons) is marked as a duplicate of a question which is closed.

The post notice reads:

> **This question already has answers here:**
>
> Closed 7 years ago.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of post notice]

Not sure if this is due to the way duplicates used to be edited into the post, or because the duplicate itself was closed, but it was pretty confusing to see.

Comment: Yeah, we know about this. Can be bydesign or declined. The issue (discussed elsewhere) is that for really old duplicates we used to inline the duplicate post links. Subsequently we record them in their own db table. But for posts preceding this the inline links exist. And for [reasons] we are unable to extract the duplicate links and delete the inlining from 100% of them. So these will look like your screenshots - the post notice just says that there is a duplicate, but the links are part of the question text.

Comment: ...unless they have been already edited out, which did happen with a lot of questions.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, if the record in table is missing/empty, you should have different message, or hide the first sentence.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The current migration notice looks like this:

[image]

This doesn't mean the question can necessarily be answered. It could be a duplicate.

I think it should be:

[image]

Comment: The language has been fixed up here, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I just noticed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40566348/1839439) in the protected banner there are two asterisks. Is this a bug related to markdown bold highlighting?

[image]

Comment: This has been fixed. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 8):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **Update to functionality**: `MigratedFrom` notices are now hidden after 60 days from migration (you can still see the migration history in the post timeline). This does not apply to the `MiratedTo` and `MigrationRejection` notices, which will continue to be shown as normal.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The notice indicating that a question was migrated from somewhere else should be removed after a fixed period of time.

[image: migrated notice]

After seven years, there is no need to highlight prominently that the question originated on a different site.

See [Hide notice for migrated questions after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299180/160917) and [Remove migration notices from destination post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339793/160917).

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>bug</kbd> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This is possibly a bug where an answer deleted on April 2019 is shown as deleted 26 months ago.

Question - [How to assert that some String contains at least one value from the List <String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550032/how-to-assert-that-some-string-contains-at-least-one-value-from-the-list-string/55550082#55550082)

Link to answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55550091/4405757

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has been mentioned in a number of places, I'll be looking into it.

Comment: @YaakovEllis your responsiveness is awesome, thanks.

Comment: Relative post close times are now being shown accurately

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

## "Highly active question" links to inaccurate help page (*protect* questions vs. *answer* protected questions)

> [image]

This is mostly fixed with TheBlackCat's "[Since you have **more than Y reputation**, you can answer the question. ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337051/177914)" proposal which is marked as <kbd>status-completed</kbd>, so I'll address only the "[Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)" part: It links to 
the [Protect questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) help section about *protecting* questions, not *answering* protected questions, which states that 15k rep is required:

> [image]

This was confusing to me, since it gave me the impression that answering was a moderator privilege. With "Since you have **more than Y reputation**, ...", this is less relevant, but for anyone who actually clicks "Learn more", I suggest one of the following things:

- Either, link to the [Remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) help section instead:

  > [image]
- Or, add to the [Protect questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) help section that

  > - *Answering* protected questions is unlocked at 10 reputation. [Learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).

since it's not immediately clear that this isn't a moderator privilege.

*(Originally reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337671), then moved to this thread.)*

Comment: The Protect Questions help section has been updated to make note of this

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Update**: after fix, the public banner now looks like this:
[image: fixed image]

---

The public duplicate banner looks like this:

[image: This question has an answer here: "Closed 1 hour ago"]

<sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778703/typescript-member-become-null-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment103842383_58778703)</sub>

Shouldn't the timestamp be below the duplicate link in a `<sub>`, like:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>
> [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com)
>
> <sub>Closed 1 hour ago</sub>

That way, the sentence would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, I also feel it's a bug. As an aside: luckily the SE developers know better than to abuse `<sub>` for formatting :-)

Comment: This has been fixed

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

This is related to the previous bug report:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337282

On old questions which were closed as "exact duplicate", such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3293038/1839439), we can see almost empty banner:

[image]

I understand that the idea is to display both banners for the time being, but I think the contents of the new banner should be adjusted.

Comment: This is [discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow?page=2&tab=votes#comment1130441_337676)

Answer (score 7):

1. On this [post 1: "Grep 'binary file matches'. How to get normal grep output? [duplicate]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512852/grep-binary-file-matches-how-to-get-normal-grep-output) I am seeing this notice

[image: Banner on question "post 1"]

2. This [post 2: How to grep a text file which contains some binary data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988379/how-to-grep-a-text-file-which-contains-some-binary-data)
   (is linked to in the notice)

So post 1 is closed as duplicate? Post 2 is not a duplicate and not closed. Post 1 refers to post 2. All good here.

**What is not good:**

- The text "Closed 2 years ago" can be read to refer to post 2 (the post that is being linked to). Actually, at first glance, I assumed this.
- There is not a clear enough indication which should be the preferred question. As a reader I am referred to another question (with answers). Yes, but post 1 has answers too. So, I might ignore the notice, upvote the question and upvote one of the answers. It doesn't help to reduce the duplicates.
- I came via Google. Why am I even seeing post 1 and not post 2?
- Why are closed questions even still visible? I never understood that.
- Why can I still upvote this question? It is closed as duplicate.
- The information "Closed as duplicate" should be integrated into the text "Closed 2 years ago". The information [duplicate] is in the title but that is visually too far away from the information in blue.
- What is the action that is expected of me to be helpful?
- Where is the information about the close reasons (in general)?
- What is the process for closing / deleting / marking as duplicate etc.?

I am sure this information is documented somewhere. It is difficult to find. Until this day the close reasons are not entirely clear to me. Duplicate is obvious. "Too broad" etc. is - at least for me - not yet obvious enough.

To really be helpful in this rollout I would like to see a before / after slideshow or something. Right now, it is just confusing. I can't easily assess the change if I don't know what was changed. Maybe the upvoting of post 1 is currently only possible because I am in this testgroup and data is being collected what my actions are. Maybe I am in the group who sees the "old" behavior.

**What are you trying to achieve?**

- reduce the amount of duplicate (and other "unwanted") questions?
- actually have the "unwanted" questions closed or deleted and no longer visible? Or at least not upvotable?

**What I like about this change:**

- Listing the other questions with number of answers
- The blue banner (can't exactly say why)

**What I would like to see:**

general:

- A nice symbol and / or individual color coding for the main close reasons.
- **Very clear** explanations for close / delete / downvote reasons and a link to this, e.g. as in ["I downvoted because" project](https://idownvotedbecau.se/). "Unclear" or "too broad" is very vague for me and can be due to a number of reasons. I would rather sacrifice "niceness" for clarity but they are not mutually exclusive and you can do both.

For "real" duplicates that have gone through a process and been identified as duplicates (which is the case here):

- removal of the duplicate (and redirect to preferred question)

For edge cases, (where there are good answers on both etc.)

- clear indication which is the canonical post
- when I search, I do not want to see the duplicate. I want to see the preferred question (e.g. redirect)
- eventually, merging of the 2 questions and removal of the duplicates

---

I would also like to point out: for many people on meta, mods, staff etc. the workflow / procedure for closing / deleting etc. and also the reasons for closing / deleting / flagging etc. seems to be clear. For me it is not (entirely). I read the help center (a while ago), I regularly use SO, and occasionally read on meta. I want to be helpful, but I am afraid the essence of SO is not yet flowing through my veins.

Comment: Re: bullet #3 - we only redirect when you're not logged in *and* there are no answers on the duplicate; this avoids the problem where you're either trying to see the duplicate explicitly, or you don't care and there are useful answer(s) to it that you might want to read before clicking through. BTW: thanks for the detailed feedback!

Comment: Raise it as a separate question/discussion. You have many points, and discuss them in comments is not convenient.

Comment: I agree. There are probably too many aspects lumped into one answer. I'd have to check though, if questions already exist and maybe filter for viability. Is there one particular point you think is worth pursuing?

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

In the old box for alerts, the background colour ws set to a light yellow. This meant that the contrast, especially for blue-coloured hyperlinks, was good and clear. Maybe it's just me, but I feel that the current light-blue colour scheme makes it harder to read hyperlinks, which is particularly significant in the case where the hyperlink contains an entire question title (because e.g. it is the link to a duplicate question). This creates unnecessary strain on my eyes, IMO.

My suggestion is to change the colour back to yellow. Either that, or adjust the background colour such that it is lighter and the colour of the hyperlinks are darker, although it seems the blue was chosen specifically to fit the colour scheme elsewhere (such as in tag backgrounds), so there could be a standardisation issue there. Changing to yellow seems the best decision to me.

Example image from a question on Math SE:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's not the clearest-looking text. I bet it looks even worse to people with certain forms of colour-blindness.

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

When I come to a question, I'm interested in the question itself. Out of habit, my eyes automatically position themselves to be where the post's body will be, however, now I'm greeted with:

> [image]

or

> [image]

**Suggestion:** Move all notices beneath the post.

**Afterthought:** If you must keep the notices in the post then try the following: If the post is closed and the person viewing the post is the OP of the question then show it in the post's body, otherwise show it beneath the post.

Comment: I think moving the notices to the top was a deliberate decision. Especially for duplicates, many users where confused by the two separate boxes (one containing the links, and one saying that it's closed and has answers *somewhere* else). However, as a feature request maybe the "post notices" could become "topic notices", and would be placed between the heading and the post instead of inside the post? This should fix your issue of "trained eyes" as well.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Script47. As @Bergi said, the decision to move all notices to the top was deliberate. We know that there are some downsides to this (some of which may be related to getting used to something new). We think that having consistent positioning for all users for all notices will outweigh these.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I just revisited [one of my first ever answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649072/1839439), which I deleted long time ago. On mobile version there is no banner no textual information that the post is deleted.

[image]

On desktop version there is a blue banner saying:

> **This post is hidden.** This post was deleted 6 years ago by the post author. Learn more.

Comment: Can you please leave a link to the question?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Added the link to the deleted answer.

Comment: deleted answers now show the appropriate notice when viewed on mobile

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906889/variable-types-in-php) I can see the same text twice.

[image]

To be pedantic, I can actually see the same message 3 times. *"Update the question so it's on-topic for Stack Overflow."* and *"Edit the question so it is on-topic for Stack Overflow."* have the same meaning.

Answer (score 5):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

It's [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337020/183280) been [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337062/183280) that "*Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege*" is unclear, but what I am actually curious about:

### How many different views are there on the new post notices?

Apparently users without the privilege to vote on the closure do see a somewhat different messages, but **what does the author see**? The message currently seems to suggest that the author gets the same view as the close voters, but that would be quite unhelpful imo.

As a power user, the information I'm primarily interested in is

- the question is closed
- for what reason (and what duplicate are linked)
- chosen by whom
- how long ago

Please make the layout so that all these bits are readily recognisable, and not distracted by more prominent (bolded) features or linebreaks.

As an author of a closed post, I need the same information but much more explanation and actionable items on that:

- What does it mean for a question to be closed/put on hold? (no answers for now, needs editing)
- What is wrong with my question (and why does that make it hard to answer/a bad fit for SO)?
- Who is responsible for the close decision (the community, not an automated process or moderator staff)
- What can I do to improve, and how does the further process look like?

Please share some screenshots of the experience an author gets as well.

*Update*: I can share a message from one of my closed questions:

[image: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.]

Also it appears that in the duplicate-question message, the sentence is change from "this post" to "your post", but otherwise it looks the same.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The details of people who closed the question, when, and the fact that it is closed are missing on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729308/how-to-add-photo-in-mysql-database-using-php)
[image]
It was closed as too-localized:
[image]

This seems to the case for most of the old reasons. The same happens for ["not a real question"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7909496/1839439)
[image]

### Update (05.11.2019):

The names are shown floating on the right of the banner, completely squished together. This is an improvement, but IMHO not good enough. It is becoming unreadable, especially with long names. Can it be moved into a separate line below the main text?
[image]

Comment: We are now showing the close dates for all close notices, to all users. And the layout bug is fixed as well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Amazing job! Well done, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This:

[image]

can be reworded to:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege.

As a user with >9000 reputation I can see the closed questions. However, such question can also be viewed by a user with 60 reputation, but this message is no longer displayed.

What does this message mean?

What a user with 9k rep sees:
[image]

What a user with 60 rep sees:
[image]

What does it mean that it is viewable by users with close privilege? Does it only mean the names of people who voted to close? What is the point in the redundant explanation of this message? I thought it meant that the question is only viewable by users >3k rep.

Also, the message says that **some** community members closed the question, and then proceeds to list them out. Why not list them straight away? These **some users** are explicitly mentioned anyway.

Comment: The upper section is shown to all users. The lower section is only shown to user's who have the privilege to perform an action based on the info - closed/reopen votes privilege or post owner.

Comment: I think I figured it out. My point is that it is confusing. This should be documented on Meta, but not displayed in the actual notice. For me it just adds noise. The little eye icon and the greyed out text are suggestive that the whole question is hidden from low-rep users.

Comment: @Dharman This is already covered in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337020/394554) and the comment linked in the comments of that answer

Answer (score 4):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Script47's <kbd>status-completed</kbd> [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337017/282094) wasn't completely fixed.

The serial comma, [used incorrectly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Resolving_ambiguity), can create an **unwelcoming** post-notice:

[image: Errant Post Notice]

The correction could have read: "Nobody, and Another Name", but that's inviting another problem ... and you need to avoid this happening again.

For example if someone's name was "downvoter", and they were second in the list, you wouldn't want that to read: "Someone the does one thing, and downvoter".

<sub>Example from: "[Why vote order is important [on hold]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337090/282094)".</sub>

Comment: I hear. We aren't going to fix this right now (it seems trivial, but localization can make things like this where you want to inject a word in a specific grammatical context exponentially more difficult)

Comment: I agree it's very difficult to fix so it can be read correctly in all circumstances. I would suggest a different seperation character, instead of a comma, use something like: | or • (bullet) or ⓵, ⓶, ⓷, ⓸, ⓹ or ↦(&map;), etc. that way it's enumerated unequivocally.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The message “*Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege*” with the little strike-through eye is inappropriate for posts closed as duplicates.

This message seems to indicate that duplicate posts should not be visible to other users, however:

- it was my understanding that duplicates are still available because they add visibility to the original question, avoid a proliferation of duplicates that are more similar to the duplicate than to the original question (say if a single problem has a number of different possible wordings, for example), etc;
- it seems from opening a dupe in a private navigation window (and finding it through a search engine − though that may be affected by caching) that accessing a duplicate question is possible even for users that are not even logged in, see screenshot below.

I think showing only the box that says “*This question already has answers here*” should be enough, otherwise some other indication that the question does not currently accept answers, which you could bundle with @Glorfindel’s rewording request. See also similar answers by [@TheLethalCoder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337020) and [@Dharman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337062) brought to my attention in the comments.

[image: view of a duplicate post in a logged in window and a non-logged in window]

Comment: That messages ambiguity is mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337020/394554), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337062/394554) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow?page=1&tab=oldest#comment1118639_337013). (It's only that section of the box (below the horizontal rule) that is not visible to not logged in users and <3k users, it's not referring to the whole post)

Comment: @NickA I went through the answers a little too fast apparently. Anyway leaving this up here as it is a little more explicit though only about one of the cases − in fact it’s a good duplicate example.

Comment: I was only aware of it because I raised the issue very early on ^^ the answers have quickly become hard to parse because of how many there are

Comment: The layout of the bottom section has been updated to hopefully make this clearer. And yes, it is intentional that users who are not logged in or who do not have sufficient rep to close/reopen will not see as many details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @YaakovEllis, much appreciated! Can you update the screenshots (or add new ones) in the original post? I’m getting the old post notices at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Post notice does not display names of close voters.

I have 20K, I am logged in and have just voted to close that particular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639229/how-to-learn-deep-learning-with-hands-on-experience-as-a-beginner)

[image]

Comment: I was going to post a bug for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511111/plotly-python-totally-free), but it appears to be a duplicate of this bug report.

Comment: This notice (and all other close notices) now always show the close date (and names of close users if you have privileges to view them)

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

For questions closed as just "off-topic" (custom close reasons and resource request), the post notice is missing features which are normally present for other closed-post notices. It's missing:

- the eye icon (`.iconEyeOff`);
- an `<hr>` separating the "**Closed.**" line from the lines only visible to the OP and >3k users (e.g. the closed-by line);
- the "(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)" line;
- and there's no indication of corrective action which the OP could do to make it on-topic.

What it currently looks like on [this example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063267/moderators-what-is-going-on-here) to a user with >3k rep:
[image]

To a user with >3k rep, I'd expect the post notices to look something like (the corrective action text is just a quick example of what might be used):
[image]

Comment: This is all by design. We are not showing a bottom section here because we are reducing info that we are showing to users who do not yet have the reopen/privilege. For these users - while they could in theory edit to reopen, in practice this is such an exceedingly rare occurrence that it is not something we will focus on. Thus only the op section is shown, and therefore there is no need for `<hr>`, the "viewable" line, the corrective action, or the eye-off icon (intended to show that the bottom section is not being shown to all users).

Comment: @YaakovEllis I'm a bit confused, the screen capture is what's shown to a >3k user. I thought one of the goals was "[consistent messaging for all cases](/questions/337013?tab=votes#comment1120305_337057)". Is that not the case? If the eye icon and "(Viewable…" text (and the `<hr>` to show to what they apply) are not valuable here, then why have them for any of the notices? For other versions of basically the same notices, the eye icon and "(Viewable…" text take up page real estate. If they're not valuable and inconsistently used, shouldn't they be removed in other versions of the notices too?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I would also expect it to look like the bottom. Going to dig into this more now.

Comment: You are on the ball again @Makyen. You found a bug on a specific edge case: where all of the close as off topic reasons on the close flags are `Other`. Fixing it now...

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks for looking into it and fixing it. Most of my time on SO/SE is spent with user-level moderation, which for me is mostly dealing with closing questions and interfacing/working with, or on, SmokeDetector. Thus, I see a *lot* of questions and answers with post notices. :-)

Comment: @YaakovEllis This also looks good. Thanks again for working on these.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In past we had duplicate notice in the body of the question. Now with the new notices we see both of them. Are there any plans to remove the old in-body notice?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187763/mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-given-in):

[image]

Comment: In the very old days, when a question was closed as a duplicate, the Community user would edit a link to the duplicate into the question. There wasn’t yet a dedicated banner indicating duplicate questions. These old duplicates need to be manually corrected. The bug you cite is unrelated to the recent changes. It’s always been there.

Comment: @CodyGray I know that, but the whole point of this change is that we unify the notice banners. I didn't tag it as bug, but as a feature request. Now that the banner is on the top of the body it collides with the old one. It would be a good idea to employ some automated tool to remove the old banners.

Comment: Mmm, automated tools *removing* information from posts is dangerous, to say the least. It is perhaps better to just handle these as you come across them.

Comment: There is ~41623 questions in the system with such in-body banner. That is a lot of manual work.

Comment: @CodyGray Is it ok to just rollback the change made by community in such cases?

Comment: Assuming that no other changes have been made since then, sure. But these are all old posts, so it's very likely that there have been subsequent edits made to them by other users.

Comment: @CodyGray Obviously what I meant is if it was the most recent edit. :D I would assume that a majority of such posts were not edited after closing as duplicate. The few examples I found have community user as the last editor.

Comment: The problem is the edge cases: the questions that *were* edited manually, including those that predate the Community edits entirely, as well as the even weirder cases where Community and an author edited *simultaneously!* There's no way to capture 100% of these, and every chance of breaking things worse in trying.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337326/can-we-bring-ancient-duplicates-up-to-date

Comment: This is fixed. In these cases the new post notice will not list the duplicates.

Comment: @YaakovEllis So that means that the old in-line banner stays? I already rolled some of them back.

Comment: @Dharman yes, the old in-line banner stays. As the duplicate links there are inline, it will take quite the effort to reliably convert them into duplicate listings (and we don't have the time for it at the moment). If they are really bothering you, the only way to take care of it right now is to get the help of a mod to reopen the question and close it right away as a duplicate (and then edit out the inline duplicate notice).

Comment: Actually the duplicate listing is already available https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbrmK.png, just the editing out is not trivial (but is it possible to just undo the effect of the community edit? There should be not conflict)

Comment: @YaakovEllis Wouldn't it be better to just leave it like that with two duplicate links and have users edit out the link in the body as they come across them? It might be confusing at first, but eventually these posts would get edited manually and it would no longer be a problem. Whereas now those posts will be left like that until a moderator or gold tag badge holder fixes them, which will take a lot longer, and [some users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391505/4284627) find that confusing as well. See my post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349996/349538).

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a "Bumped by Community user" notice on the question page, when it was, well, bumped by the Community user.

Can it please be brought back?

[Recent example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/316759/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Make it obvious when opening the close vote dialog that the question can't be close-voted because it has a bounty in it.

Currently, opening the dialog and clicking Vote To Close after selecting a reason looks like this:

> [image]

I think that we should be blocked from VTCing a bountied question like in the old UI.

Comment: That's not really related to post notices. (aka it's NAA here)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard I'd say it's related because the old UI blocked us from CVing when opening the dialog, but the new doesn't.

Comment: So that's a bug, caused by the new post notice somehow, but still, not directly related IMO. (So better be posted as new bug report)

Comment: Agree with @ShadowThePrincessWizard - this is not related to post notices

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Spam-deleted answers, if they need a banner link at all, should link to [deleted-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), not to the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Example: [Spam-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49876848). Banner is currently:

> **This post is hidden**. It was flagged as spam or offensive content and [deleted](/help/roomba) last year by [Community](/users/-1/community)♦.

but, like [other deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892858), it should probably link to `/help/deleted-answers` instead of to `/help/roomba`.

Comment: `/help/roomba` is for the specific subcase of deleted answers that were auto-deleted by community. So in this case, it is the more appropriate help page.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? The roomba automatically deletes *questions* only, and does nothing to answers. Nothing described on `/help/roomba` has to do with deleted answers, so linking to it when an *answer* (but not its parent question) is deleted doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right. I didnt notice that you were talking specifically about answers - where roomba indeed does not run. This will be fixed.

Comment: The fix is live now. Help link now points to deleted-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On this Q: [Is it considered poor form to answer old and inactive questions? (thread resurrection)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339753/is-it-considered-poor-form-to-answer-old-and-inactive-questions-thread-resurre) the suggested dupe comment hasn't been removed after dupe closure with the suggested target. The comment doean't appear to be edited, which would invalidate the auto deletion.

Perhaps because the comment is not by one of the people that closed the Q?

[image]
Click for larger version.

Comment: @JohnOmielan said user doesn't have the reputation to vote to close, so can't be one of the listed members. They can however flag as a dupe, which results in the same comment, AFAIK.

Comment: @John I can see there are no deleted comments on that post, and that the comment that's there seems to have been raised when the post was flagged. So I think this is definitely a change of how things used to work, as far as I remember those were always deleted when the post ended up closed too.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Thanks for the additional info, and to you as well Luuklag. I should have checked the user's reputation first to see they couldn't have voted to close themselves. Also, I've deleted my comment as it's not correct or particularly useful here.

Comment: @JohnOmielan It was a fair question, so no need to have deleted that. Anyways have a nice day.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339762/369802 < Two comments deleted by community when it was closed (one for duplicate, one for off-topic/other). It does seem like the autocomment for duplicates is posted when someone flags (not votes), but not cleaned up?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, my auto-comment there appears to have been deleted. So I dont get your point tbh. But yes, when it originates from a flag it appears to stay, otherwise it gets deleted it appears.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point! To provide a bit more 'proof' that some comments seem to stick around because they are raised by flag, instead of vote :) Though now I also wonder if community always cleaned up both 'off-topic/other' and 'duplicate' comments, when closing, or used to just pick the one that the question is actually 'closed' as?

Answer (score 1):

The notice on closed posts ends with a full sentence that doesn't finish with a period.

[image]

> (List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege)

This seems inconsistent with the overall use of periods in the post notices because they usually have several sentences all finishing with a period. The Stacks style guide also seems to suggest the [use of period to finish the sentence](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods).

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337108/345161) suggestes moving the post notices back to the bottom of the post (it's also where I got the images). I'm aware that it was a deliberate decision to move them to the top of the post though and so this is unlikely to happen.

Instead consider moving them out of the post's body and above the horizontal rule. *That* is the location for meta information of the post and a more appropriate location for the notices. A change was made to move the "asked, active, viewed" labels there from the side bar so it makes sense to keep it consistent and have the notices in that location too.

They aren't part of the post or the post's content but information surrounding it and as such would be better placed above the horizontal rule.

> [image]

or

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are going to leave them as-is.

Answer (score -1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) / [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow/337032?noredirect=1#comment1121722_337032))

The way the system is set up it only shows the users that closed the question, when you have the appropriate privileges to re-open a question.

In case of a (historically)locked question, only moderators have the privileges to re-open. This makes the closure notice not useful and hence noise.

### Can we *not* show the closed notice when a post is (historically)locked.

Comment: No, I'd still like to know if and why a historically locked question was closed.