# "Highly active question" banner text has a couple of stray asterisks

Tags: bug, status-completed, protected-questions

The banner text for protected questions currently reads:

> **[Highly active question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)**.** You have enough reputation to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

What are those two asterisks doing there? Looks like someone made a Markdown typo.

Comment: New Post Notices bug reports went in this topic. This issue now appears to be fixed. [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) --- Feedback about the Post Notices go there, as an *answer* (feedback).

Comment: @Rob that post is historically locked, it can't receive any more answers.

Comment: @RobertColumbia ... and it didn't exist when I asked, and it wasn't proposed as a dupe here until after this bug was fixed and this question's fate was largely moot. But, meh. Since it is fixed, it's of no consequence what happens to this question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you saw a brief bug in the new Post Notices rollout - resolved since by the lovely Yaakov :)