# "Highly active question" banner is misleading

Tags: bug, user-interface, hot-questions, wording, active

Today I noticed this banner on [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112586/90068):
[image: Screenshot with "Highly active question" banner]

What exactly is that supposed to mean?
I do NOT think it means this is a highly active question, and I very much doubt it ever was.  As seen in the line above, it was last active 1 year, 11 months ago, the moment it was asked.  The Q&A [each got an upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/90068/wbt?tab=reputation) today and another Nov. 19 (17 days ago), Aug 21 (107 days ago), and January 8 2018 (697 days ago).
As far as I can tell, it never made the HNQ list.  Neither the question, nor its sole answer posted simultaneously, were ever edited, nor were they ever commented on.

Why is this being characterized as "highly active?"  Can that inaccurate wording be fixed to better reflect reality?

Comment: This is probably better as an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/369802) to the question announcing the change and requesting feedback? In fact, it also has a post [discussing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339709/369802)...

Comment: Considering that this is the top voted answer there and two staff members have commented on that answer, I think that's an unfair statement. There's a huge difference between how we can respond to feedback about policy and how we can change site features. We're much more limited in the former than the latter.

Comment: @Catija Why would you be more limited in being able to follow the site's policies as announced, including retroactive actions to correct what was done contrary to the policy?  Those steps should be easy, just a few minutes of someone executing the change.  Site features require dev time and would seem harder to fulfill.

Comment: Okay. What makes you think that posting this question as an answer to a post requesting feedback on the new post notices will get you a suspension, but leaves you feeling comfortable enough to post it as a question instead?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell This is written as a UI bug report, clearly showing the mismatch between text and reality, that can be independently discussed, answered and responded to, which is more constructive than just (possibly prohibited) negative feedback; response to a feedback post would more likely be seen as the latter.

Comment: It's not a bug though. It's [tag:status-bydesign] and the answers to the questions you're asking are more likely to be found at the post that announced the change.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I don't see it marked as status-bydesign, even accounting for the fact that answers to a feedback post aren't individually tagged.  I see a lot of people complaining about the language and discussing if the questions should remain protected, which is a different issue than making the language in the banner correlate better with reality.  Feel free to tag this question [status-bydesign] if you want to emphasize that the lack of correlation is intentional.

Comment: @Luuklag No. That post clearly states "our holistic redesign of all post notices will prioritize ... Giving actionable, understandable information for the vast majority of public viewers" and the message that is the subject of this question is the opposite of that.

Comment: Said post specifically asks for feedback: "General feedback is welcome on this post, as are feature-request and bug reports. We promise to read everything, and will do our best to engage with the community to address concerns that are raised." So this is perfectly posted over there as an answer. But you've been told that before I see.

Comment: I can see in my Notifications a comment on this question that "I'm voting to close this as off-topic..." but when clicking through, can't see the full comment; it just [scrolls to the top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339762/highly-active-question-banner-is-misleading?noredirect=1#comment1134904_339762). I strongly disagree; this isn't off-topic for MSE.

Comment: Note that the linked question is currently locked: _This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic_. This is another nice example of a post notice that is false (the announcement was and is certainly on-topic on Meta.SE) and, because the original question and the mentioned answer cannot be voted or commented on anymore, maybe the question here can be un-duplicated so the issue can be discussed further without meta-meta-discussion, and hopefully the wording of the banner can be improved.

Comment: @Marijn: The ["New Post Notices are live network-wide"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) post is locked now, yes, after plenty of feedback was solicited from that thread. A question about the post notices *now* presumably wouldn't be closed as a duplicate of that thread. This question, on the other hand, was posted literally the day after that network-wide announcement was made, while the conversation was still ongoing there.

Comment: However, a question about post notices *now* **would** rightly be closed as a duplicate of this one, which is already closed.