# Remove migration notices from destination post

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, migrated-questions, post-notices, migration-notice

As part of the roll-out of new [post notices](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/?cb=1), questions that were migrated now show a notice at the top indicating that they were migrated.

[image: migrated notice]

I ran across a question today that is seven years old.  After seven years, there is no need to highlight prominently that the question originated on a different site.  This is the very first thing we are showing people who visit that page -- yet it's one of the least important things about the question.

Suggestion: The notice indicating that a question was migrated from somewhere else should be removed after a fixed period of time (say, 30 days).

It's unfortunate that this notice is shown at the top of questions.  It's not what we should lead off with.  It's not relevant any longer (who cares?  it's irrelevant; it might have been relevant when it was first migrated, but seven years now).  It's distracting.  It also potentially leaves the impression that there is something wrong with the question or some reason why it needs to be marked, marking the question in perpetuity.

A similar request was made two years ago ([Hide notice for migrated questions after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299180/160917)).  However, that was before the new post notices.  Back then, the "migrated" notice was shown at the *bottom*, underneath the question -- so the first thing that people saw was the question, and the "migrated" notice was less problematic.  Now, that notice has been moved to the top, above the body of the question, and it is more problematic.

Note: I'm talking about the post notice on the destination site, not on the source site.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica, thanks for pointing to that post from two years.  It's indeed closely connected.  However, I think the context is different now that post notices have been moved to the top.  I agree that it's not a priority to remove "migrated" notices when they are at the bottom, but I think that the situation is a bit different when they are at the top.  I will leave it to you and others whether you want to count it as a duplicate or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A proposed philosophy of question migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration) - People think it's important to maintain the notice because sometimes the question isn't edited to suit the site it's moved to (possibly leaving it an *odd fit*). Thus it's thought that keeping the notice permanently and displaying it is required (sufficiently often, but not always). -- The side-issue that the location moved isn't the fault of the first principle, but a fault with the change.

Comment: While I get that this is more relevant today given the recent changes to the notices, and while I agree with this request (in fact, I've posted an answer to the notice announcement requesting the same thing), per current meta policy and consensus, since the other one hasn't been answered or given a status tag, this can be closed as a duplicate. A better way to raise attention to this would be to post an answer there. See [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: Probably this question should be [an *answer* on the Post Notices Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/282094) (and Feedback request) requesting: "Migration Notices ought to be moved back under the question where they used to be.", This is why ... [^](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339793/remove-migration-notices-from-destination-post#comment1135088_339793) .

Comment: @Rob I've already posted such an answer on the announcement.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog, yes just agreeing with you and D.W., and supporting [my close comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339793/remove-migration-notices-from-destination-post?noredirect=1#comment1135091_339793). *They* are in favor of their decision and sometimes are resistant to perceived *pushback* (over considering it as an attempt to offer constructive feedback).

Comment: @Rob, no, it doesn't.  I'm making a feature request, not asking a question.  I don't see anything there that addresses my feature request.  As far as the substantive argument, in my opinion after 7 years there is no reason why we need to maintain the notice.  After 7 years, if it hasn't been edited and is off-topic, then it really doesn't matter how the question ended up on our site; either you close it, or you edit it, but knowing that it was migrated is of no use in that decision.

Comment: D.W., whether you like moved or removed it should go [where Sonic wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339793/remove-migration-notices-from-destination-post?noredirect=1#comment1135104_339793), leaving your question here (and closed) leaves your input (voice) hidden.

Comment: Here are a couple of examples of FRs and bugs being marked as duplicates of the announcement, that's where feedback goes. Examples: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339799/282094 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339762/282094, both closed.