# "This question was migrated" seems placed much more prominently than is warranted

Tags: bug, questions, migration

See [this question on Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-from-one-directory-to-another)

[image]

The first things each visitor reads when seeing this question are:

1. The title
2. A message that the question was migrated *8 years ago*
3. The actual question

This seems really off to me; I think the migration message is more like *footnote content* at this point rather than almost-as-important-as-the-title. I'm pretty sure this is a recent change because I definitely didn't even *notice* this message last time I saw this question (probably within the last month).

Was this intentional, or a bug?

Comment: [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), post your feedback there.

Comment: Ah thanks! I assumed there was a post about this _somewhere_ but didn't even know where to look.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339793/294055

Comment: I've already requested the same thing in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339794/377214) to [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). Also, the notice does indeed trump other notices such as the protection notice.

Comment: I like the idea of it being prominent at first, but after a certain amount of time it becomes a more subtle footnote.

Comment: I don't think this is something that'll change. I remember it being mentioned that they want to keep it consistent so they I doubt they'll change it just for this case.