Post notice for protected questions is confusing; please rephrase it to make it clearer
The post notice for protected questions currently reads

Highly Active Question. Earn 10 reputation (not counting the association bonus) in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

There are bunch of issues with this, some of them pointed out on this recent duplicate and in the comments below this post. Here are 6 of them:

What if I have 5 reputation at the time of reading the post notice? The current post notice makes it seem like I need to get to 15 reputation to answer the question, which is false, I only need to get to 10 reputation to answer the question.
It seems some user(s) are thinking that "Earn 10 reputation" means "you gain 10 reputation", which is wrong, rather than the correct meaning of "you must get 10 reputation".
I don't see what purpose the "in order" serves.
The 1 reputation you get for signing up is counted towards the 10 reputation required to answer protected questions. The current version of the post notice seems like you must get 10 more reputation in addition to 1 you get for signing up to answer protected questions.
The notice says "Highly Active Question", but protected questions are not necessarily highly active, or even active at all.
If you, at one point, earned 10 reputation, then lost some, the current version of the post notice makes it seem like you would still be able to answer protected questions, while in fact you are not able to do so.

Could these issues please be fixed? My draft would be:

To answer this question you need to have at least 10 reputation on this site (not counting the association bonus). The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.


"Do X in order to be able to do Y" is common English. At what point is any fluency in the language of a website not prerequisite to using that language and that website..

It's totally clear for me, and your suggestion would be as confusing, if not more, for others. My point is, it's impossible to keep it short while making it crystal clear for 100% of the people. If someone isn't sure what it means, that's what meta sites are for, to look for the meaning of such things then it's easy to understand.

I don't see why this is being negatively received. It takes multiple reads for a non-native English speaker to understand that it's an imperative sentence rather than a declarative sentence, especially given that the specific construction (without a subject at the beginning, e.g., "you") isn't even allowed in many languages, such as Hindi. A simple wording change to add a subject at the beginning would greatly improve the experience for non-English speakers.

@ShadowWizard If you've noticed, I've made many edits to FAQs to make things clearer after things that are technically noted in them but not clear enough come up as posts here. I don't consider this any different.

Earn 10 reputation in order to...  is perfectly fine and understandable but it could be clarified further if it said: In order to answer this question you must have earned 10 reputation (not counting the association bonus) …

If the banner is adjusted then maybe at the same time the wording "highly active" can be changed, which is often not true as the question is not actually active (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339762/highly-active-question-banner-is-misleading).

@Sonic suppose it will be changed. Then someone else will come in 6-8 weeks and say "hey! It's not clear! Change it!" and they change again. And again. And again. See my point? For each person it's different. For me, as a non-native English reader, it's totally clear, even if I put behind my experience, hence I oppose changing it.

What happens if somebody "earns" 10 reputation or more and then loses some of that reputation to fall below a reputation of 10? As it stands, the current phrasing can be read to imply that you only need to earn 10 reputation once. The remove new user restrictions is not clear on this point either.

All rep requirements must be met at the time the action is attempted. This one is no different.

Just want to make sure that the minus reputation earning scenario is handled by the rewording.

I have so far seen some people think this is neutral and others think it is helpful. If no one thinks its harmful and plenty think its helpful, why not do it?

We can't have the perfect banner, there will always be those saying it's not clear and suggest trillion changes - that just will never end. That is why I don't support changing it. The current one is good. Let's not fix things that are not broken.

Yes of course we can never get perfect, but I think that the version I am suggesting fixes the other 5 issues I brought up (which I thing most people would agree is broken)@ShadowWizard

I'm a native English speaker, and I find the current phrasing a bit of a head scratcher, and I have to actively try to figure out what it is saying. Changing "Earn ..." to "You must have earned ...." would eliminate 95% of the confusion.

The whole thing is backward to me. It reads Status->What you can do->What the status means. It should be Status->What this means->What you can do. E.g. "Highly Active Question. This question has been protected from spam and non-answer activity. To answer it, you need to have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."

@Mari-LouA You can do with one word change: "Reach 10 reputation..."

Reach 10 reputation would imply that losing rep afterwards you still answer protected questions@Michaelcomelately
