# Where are the names of the user(s) that closed a question displayed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, users

[My SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020153/how-to-trigger-a-listboxitems-style-change-on-the-underlying-object-state-chang) has been closed.

Now, there is [an official SO help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) for people who disagree with the closure reasons. One of its paragraphs says:

> If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the
> question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this
> only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should
> be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do
> reconsider their decisions.

How can I say if a moderator closed my question if the only message I got is:

[image: closure banner displaying a reason but not which users were involved]

Also, basing on [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174183/whats-the-goal-of-listing-the-users-that-voted-to-close-a-question) it seems there were times when question closers were indeed displayed to the person that asked the question.

Has the community's goal of making people accountable for their actions changed?  Or maybe, the information is still displayed somewhere and I just cannot find it?

Mark that I'm not asking for means for a personal vendetta, but only want to have a means **to follow the official help page**.

Comment: You can look at the questions timeline to see who closed a question. I don't think pinging those users in comments will work though https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340340/names-of-close-voters-are-not-visible-in-the-post-notice-but-in-the-revision-his

Comment: I've [asked a follow-up question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369379/295232) to adjust/remove this text.

Comment: Actually, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/295232) is the right link to find information about when/why it changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### It's viewable in the question's timeline, which can be accessed via the clock icon to the left of the post, but...

...that help center article isn't giving very good advice on how to get a question reopened.  Flags for moderator attention to reopen a question are likely to be declined.  You're better off editing the question to address the close reason (and checking the box saying that the edits resolve the original close reason), voting to reopen if you have the required reputation, and/or posting on the site's per-site meta if those options don't work.  There's a lot more information in [this FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/165261).

[image: Screenshot of the icons to the left of the question, with the timeline button at the bottom circled]

In the timeline, you should see a "Closed" event with a list of the close voters and a close reason (here, the close reason is "Needs more focus"):

[image: Screenshot of "Closed" timeline entry showing a timestamp of "yesterday", three close voters, and "Needs more focus"]