# Adjust the Help Center text about flagging a question for moderator attention to have it reopened

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, help-center, vote-to-reopen

Currently, the Help Center article about [reopening closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) says:

> If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

Now, [close voters are no longer shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/295232) to users without the Close Votes privilege, so they [have a hard time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369375/295232) following that procedure. (The close voters are still shown in the question's timeline.)

Also, there might be other ways to contact close voters: via [comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310869/295232), provided that they were the only close voters. This holds for both ♦ moderators and gold tag badge holders using their [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232).

I feel like this paragraph should either

- have an introductory "If you have enough reputation to see who closed your question ...", in which case it would make sense to add a few words about the comment replies as well
- or it should be omitted altogether. In my experience, it doesn't happen that often. I'm a moderator on six sites, I've seen a few custom flags asking for reopening but usually on questions which were closed by community members.

Thoughts?

Comment: The notice **never** shows users who closed their own questions, *even if* they have enough rep to see it on others' questions.