# Closed post message "List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege" is misleading

Tags: discussion, bug, closed-questions, post-notices

[image]

It says

> List of close voters is **only** viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege

Apparently, that's not the case as mentioned in

[How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements/332502#332502)

It's not **only** viewable by those users with privilege, but by everyone, even anonymous users in timeline/revision history. This obscurity/transparency strategy was defended along various thoughtlines, but nevertheless, the notice is misleading, giving the impression to close voters, that their names are not viewable by those without privilege.

Comment: *List of close voters is only viewable **here** by users with the close/reopen votes privilege* ... pr0blam solved.

Comment: or just remove that text entirely

Comment: Some related posts here on this site: [Where are the names of the user(s) that closed a question displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369375) and [Names of close-voters are not visible in the post notice but in the revision history and timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340340).

Comment: @rene  That still doesn't explicitly state that it's visible elsewhere. You have to play word games to get to that conclusion from that wording. I think Ethan's suggestion of removing it entirely is the most clear cut, non-confusing strategy here.

Comment: I said this earlier somewhere but can't find its source: I always thought that sentence was added by the UX designer as an implementation sticky-note for devs and maybe managers. I'm still surprised the sticky note made into production, let alone that it refuses to be peeled off ....

Comment: @rene Actually, no, that doesn't solve it, because you're not shown the list of close voters for your own questions, even if you're a mod. Thus, it would need to be something like "The list of close voters is only viewable here by users with the close/reopen votes privilege who are not the question author."

Comment: @TheMaster The point of not showing the list of close voters to users who can't vote to close and the question author is to prevent them from trivially obtaining that information. Particularly for the question author, the goal is to prevent people "taking revenge" upon the close voters. Thus, stating the list of close voters is viewable somewhere else is counterproductive. In other words, it's specifically not supposed to say that the list is visible elsewhere. Also, stating that it's visible elsewhere doesn't seem useful, because that text isn't shown to those who can't see the list there.

Comment: ^ that, and where the first user flagged the question they sometimes aren't included in the list, anywhere. So while it could be expanded to include a link to the FAQ I think [rene 's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385961/closed-post-message-list-of-close-voters-is-only-viewable-by-users-with-the-clo#comment1286980_385961) is sufficient; if not completely accurate, people can enter and **leave** the list without a trace while encouraging others to VTC - so every possibility isn't available in the banner.