# Close voters can be seen by those without the privilege to do so

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, privileges, post-notices

This is what I see from my account (which has the close vote privilege):
[image]
It says *"Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege,"* yet this is not true.

---

Here is evidence for that. This is what users without the close vote privilege see (which makes us think what the above said is true)
[image]

But if you click that button, well, they too can see what's *forbidden*:

[image]
Is this a possible bug?

Comment: I believe the visibility of the close voters in the post notice is collapsed to those without the privilege so that it's easier to digest. and because it's not very useful for those without the privilege to see this information right in the post notice. There's slightly different information displayed here when you're the post author, instructing you on what to do next. I don't think the users who voted to close are meant to be kept secret, per se.

Comment: In the end you can also find this info from SEDE as the close voters are stored in the posthistory table. Let's not go paranoia and try to turn this into fort Knox.

Comment: I brought this up tangentially [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337104/323179) and nobody said anything. I don’t think that the names of who votes to close is a secret (the information is also available in the app and the revision history).

Comment: @Laurel why why such a message for those with previledges?

Comment: @rene then why such meesage for those with vote previledge?

Comment: To not overflow new users with a ton of information that is not actionable. There is no value in knowing up-front who closed a question. Or it must be for the revenge votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The users who voted to close aren't meant to be kept secret. The panel that displays who voted to close (and whether or not they're a gold badge holder using their [dupe-hammer powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/622284)) isn't useful to newer users who don't have access to close/reopen votes.

In essence, post notices were designed to be as succinct as possible, and only display relevant information to relevant people. The question author gets information on what to do next if their question is closed, and close voters get to see who voted to close and for what reason in this panel because they have an active interest in casting votes to reopen, or editing the question so that it's reopenable (if possible.)

Users who do not have access to this privilege do not have such access, and thus don't really *need* to see the expanded information, but it's not meant to be secret. You can browse the timeline or, as [rene pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346765/close-voters-can-be-seen-by-those-without-the-privilege-to-do-so#comment1161027_346765), browse the Data Explorer.