# Show users what the all close messages say for a site

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Due to the [recent changes to close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337104/323179), I’m having a hard time figuring out what the close reasons say as there seems to be three different messages per close reason per site:

- One for the author
- One for people with close/reopen privileges
- One shown to everyone (though this might also be shown to the two groups above)

(Does the ability to customize these include the network wide reasons like “too broad”? Has this even been deployed across the network yet? No idea, but not knowing that is a symptom of the problem.)

While most of these close reason messages can be tediously found by someone with close vote privileges, that’s not the way it should be. (And how would I know what what the author sees without asking each type of off topic question?) This information (ie all three bullet points) should be available for everyone because I find this information to be extremely useful:

- As a new user/non-member of a site: what’s commonly off topic here?
- As a close voter/close voter to be/flagger: which reason is most helpful for this potentially off topic question?
- As a meta user: are the reasons we have good or should they be changed?

**Can we please have an easy way to see the text of each close vote reason for all users?**

Probably the best place for this info is a Help Center article because it’ll be in the same place for each site and can hopefully pull the exact messages without having to be updated.

Comment: Only Community specific reasons can be customized. :) Yes, all sites can use the new tool.