# Is there a complete list of private guidance for network-wide closure reasons?

Tags: support, data-explorer, close-reasons

There is a difference between what others users see and what the post owner sees when a question is closed.

For example, when a question is closed as a duplicate users see<sup>1</sup>:

> Some community members have associated this post with a similar question.

While the post owner sees<sup>1</sup>:

> Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, [ask a new one](/questions/ask).

---

For community specific reasons, the list of guidance markdown can be pulled fairly easily through SEDE. For example, [Stack Overflow's post owner vs public guidance](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1573733/current-close-reason-feedbacks)

But there doesn't seem to be (or at least I can't find) anywhere in SEDE or on MSE a complete list of the current guidance for the network-wide/universal closure reasons.

Is there such a list somewhere (*e.g.* in the help center, mod tools, on MSE, *etc.*) or a way to access this information through SEDE?

---

<sup>1</sup> There is variation based on whether a the question was closed single handedly or by multiple users, and variation if it was closed with a single duplicate target or multiple (but not really the primary point of this question)

Comment: There's a complete list in the source code :) I do not know of a publicly available one, [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/295232) (and linked posts) list a few of them but I'm not sure they're up to date.

Comment: That's a shame... I'm trying to put together a meta post on MSO to discuss updating some of our community specific guidance, and wanted to just put everything up there (so that we can address as much as possible while we're discussing it). Welp, I guess I'm off to try and get a questions closed for every reason so I can see the post owner feedback... ( jokes XD )

Comment: @HenryEcker it would need a community wiki, someone would have to search the posts for all the banners. Besides, posts closed in the past can have banners that are no longer used in new closures but still displayed on the older posts.

Comment: Or... somewhere there exists a table with the information. Like wherever the IsUniversal=true values are from [CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1623430) Or it could even be listed in the 10k-tool Question-close-stats where there's a table of current and prior reasons (currently not including universal reasons).