# Why is the "Highly active" label still present even after all activity has ceased?

Tags: support, wording, protected-questions

I was browsing Aviation by top voted, and came across [Why does Chicago O'Hare have a penalty box?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11318/why-does-chicago-ohare-have-a-penalty-box)

Asked and answered in 2014, the most recent activity on this question includes:

- 3 years ago: an answer edit
- 7 years ago: edits to answer and question, four new comments
- 8 years ago: the most recent answer

However, at the bottom of the page it says:

[image]

Why is this question labelled with the text "highly active"?

<sub>With a  icon I might add! What is fueling the fire in that flame 8 years later, and can I get some of it?</sub>

Comment: [It was protected](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/11318/timeline#history_632099dd-8eb0-4532-858e-ff092c291630)

Comment: Haha well it certainly adds context. The question is, "why is a not-active question marked as highly active", and so your context mostly just shifts the question to "why are protected questions described as 'highly active'". Would it be better to edit and rephrase this question, or to open a new one?

Comment: The protection only really limits new users (<9 rep) from posting answers. And protection tends to be applied where brand new accounts keep posting answers to a question. Even if those answers are duplicates, or worse - irrelevant, or spam or otherwise do not belong there. [That question has 6 deleted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/edit/1822044?parentid=11318). I'd hazard a guess, it was attracting answers from brand new accounts.

Comment: So perhaps I can venture an answer to my own question. "It is marked as 'highly active' because, once upon a time, it was highly active and a moderator protected it from low-quality answers. The phrase 'highly active' is likely a misnomer, since it can be applied irrespective of activity levels, and is not automatically removed from questions with truly high activity once the activity levels have diminished."

Comment: I think basically all of that was covered in the FAQ. That protection and highly active are the same thing, who and how can apply protection, when is protection applied.

Comment: I'm making the case here that the words "highly active" are misleading to users. The fact that one can read 2 pages of FAQ on meta in order to understand why the UX of the site is obviously incorrect does not change the fact that the text is misleading to users.

Comment: Perhaps another answer on a deeper level might be, "Because we need a mechanism to protect answers that can be applied by moderators, but which is communicated more intuitively to users. An unfortunate side effect is that, unless a moderator removes the label as part of a review, it becomes outdated and makes the site look broken. But we only have so much moderator capability to remove the protection from non-active questions, so that's what users get."

Comment: That's just bad wording for protected questions. One of many "improvements" SE made over time, which caused a worse user experience, in the name of... not sure what.

Comment: As for the faq, it does not explain the wording and why they chose to do the change in wording, so not duplicate. This is a separate question.

Comment: @CoryKlein The case that "highly active" is misleading [was made to SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337053/271271) when they changed the post notices back in 2019 ([on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/271271); [on Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/271271)). The [post notices used to explicitly say "protected"](https://web.archive.org/web/20190105035058/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch#comments-link-45049899).

Comment: Also: You don't have the privilege of seeing deleted posts on [aviation.se], so have no way of knowing what the question's actual activity is. You're just assuming that there isn't recent activity. For this specific case, I'm not sure that fact really matters, as the protected status of a question does tend to linger long after any "highly active" period. The problem, however, really is calling the "protected" state "highly active", as something actually, currently being "highly active" is merely one use for "protected". At least in my experience, it's the least common use of "protection".

Comment: I think it's reasonable to request that the wording be improved.

Answer (score -1):

Because the "highly active" label is applied manually by moderators as part of [the Protected Questions feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/154666) and is **not** automatically removed once the activity has ceased.

In fact, a question does not necessarily need to be highly active in order to be labelled as such. Any moderator simply needs to decide that the question warrants protection.

Because of the above two facts, the phrase "highly active" can end up being a misnomer in some situations such as in the question you discovered.

I am not familiar with the history whereby the protected question text was decided, but I presume if the text was changed to be 100% accurate in all situations where it was applied (such as questions with low activity) then that would make it *less* functional in the most common scenario where the protection is in fact highly correlated to high activity.

Your example question likely does not need protection any longer, and an Aviation moderator should remove it, which would resolve the inconsistency in the UX on that question.

Hypothetically, SE could implement the automatic removal of protection on similar questions given some criteria (say, once enough time has passed and activity levels have dropped), but such functionality does not exist today and it can only be removed by moderator action.

Finally, non-moderator users such as yourself could consider flagging the question to moderators if you felt this would improve the question, but it would be up to the moderator to make a final decision.

[image]

Comment: As a moderator, I'll heartily agree it's a major misnomer a lot of the time. However, I would recommend *against* flagging the post just because it is no longer active. You don't know how much spam and other off-topic crud gets posted to old, inactive posts.

Comment: If you would phrase this as a feature request to rename the feature because it being a misnomer, I would support it. If you propose flagging the post is an acceptable course of action here, I have no choice but to be against it.

Comment: "applied manually by moderators" appears inaccurate in this case (protection was applied by user14897), and is likely inaccurate in most cases. While protection can be applied manually by both moderators and users with the [protect questions privilege](/help/privileges/protect-questions), I believe the vast majority of questions that are "protected" are automatically protected by the system as a consequence of having multiple answers by low-reputation users deleted, as described in [answer to: "Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers"](/a/89971/271271).

Comment: Related: *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di)*. [Protect questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions): 1750 reputation points (Private beta), 3500 reputation points (beta), and 15000 reputation points (full)